# re instantiate a PagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, adapter

How can i re-instantiate a ViewPager ?
My adapter looks like this :

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
            return NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)cxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_result, null);
        //
        TextView title = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.search_result_title);
        TextView body = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.search_result_body);
        TextView byline = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.search_result_byline);
        TextView day = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.search_result_date_day);
        TextView month = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.search_result_date_month);
        TextView year = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.search_result_date_year);
        TextView page = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.search_result_page);
        TextView page_max = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.search_result_page_max);
        //
        title.setText(list_title.get(position).toString());
        body.setText(list_body.get(position).toString());
        day.setText(list_day.get(position).toString());
        month.setText(list_month.get(position).toString());
        year.setText(list_year.get(position).toString());
        byline.setText(list_byline.get(position).toString());
        page.setText(Integer.toString(position+1));
        page_max.setText(Integer.toString(NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS));
        //
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(layout,0);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view==((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {}


    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {}

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View arg0) {}

}
```

I found a way to reload a bunch of data into the list, but how can i reload all the pages from the onPostExecute (Asynctask).

Answer (score 3):

Add following to your MyPagerAdapter class:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

and call

```
myPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

from onPostExecute of your AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

I think calling notifyDataSetChanged(); using the adapter reference will solve your problems.

Comment: where do i have to call it ? after the execution from Asynctask ?

Comment: on the onPostExecute of your AsyncTask. After loading everything that you want to change on your list.

Comment: the thing is working but it's odd because i need to change pages and return to see my new pages..

Comment: Using the adapter reference use setCurrentItem(0);

Comment: I still need to change my pages to see the changes.

Comment: Using the view pager reference, try invalidate(); after the nofityDataSetChanged();

Comment: I have confirmed that my previous answers did not work. See my new answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view/7287121#7287121).