# How to force ViewPager to re-instantiate its items

Tags: android, android-widget, android-viewpager

I am using `ViewPager` to allow user to swipe between its views. Is there a way how to force this `ViewPager` to reload/re-instantiate its views in case that they are no longer valid or needs to be refreshed? I tried to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on its adapter but this does not invoke `instantiateItem()` method again.

### EDIT

Here is the class that extends from ViewPager and its adapter definision. Bellow is the `refresh()` method that I call when I want to force to refresh items.

```
public class DayFlipper extends ViewPager {

public class FlipperAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return DayFlipper.DAY_HISTORY;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View container) {
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "instantiateItem(): " + position);

        Date d = DateHelper.getBot();
        for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            d = DateHelper.getTomorrow(d);
        }

        d = DateHelper.normalize(d);

        CubbiesView cv = new CubbiesView(mContext);
        cv.setLifeDate(d);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(cv, 0);
        // add map
        cv.setCubbieMap(mMap);
        cv.initEntries(d);
        return cv;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((CubbiesView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View container) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((CubbiesView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {

    }

}

    ...

    public void refresh() {
    getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged()..  should do it. can you post some code..

Comment: I added code snippet. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: my reason for this problem - my `destroyItem()` method had an incorrect class cast in it (left over from tutorial code) - so the view was never being destroyed.

Comment: when i refresh the viewpagers data, first two view pagers are not refresh and other view pager data is changing. please help me

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I have found a solution. It is just a workaround to my problem but currently the only solution.

[ViewPager PagerAdapter not updating the View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view/7287121#7287121)

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
   return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Does anyone know whether this is a bug or not?

Comment: Not really; `getItemPosition` is used to notify the `ViewPager` whether or not to refresh an item, and to avoid updates if the items at the visible positions haven't changed. The "bug" here is the non-obvious and/or non-existent solution to refresh the visible items from client code.

Comment: It sounds like for what you need this for there is no bug in this code. You are basically just saying you need to update each item when a change to the dataset happens. The only difference I would say would be if you want to update only specific pages which would take a bit more logic than this.

Comment: for this answer remove r from "gord" .. thanku man.

Comment: when i refresh the viewpagers data, first two view pagers are not refresh and other view pager data is changing. please help me

Comment: this causes                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions

Comment: Do you still have the "smooth" swipe with this solution?

Answer (score 174):

Had the same problem. For me it worked to call

```
viewPage.setAdapter( adapter );
```

again which caused reinstantiating the pages again.

Comment: Not sure I like this approach, but it worked for me too.

Comment: viewPager.setAdapter(null) will clear all pages.

Comment: when i refresh the viewpagers data, first two view pagers are not refresh and other view pager data is changing. please help me

Comment: thanks for this solution. but re-adding adapter is good idea?

Comment: viewPage.setAdapter( adapter ); saved my life!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: This approach is working for me - however as other have mentioned is it a good idea to re-set the adapter ?

Comment: This is the perfect answer for viewpager2 and FragmentStateAdapter.  A whole day i spent for refreshing the tabs. Saved my day.

Comment: Nice answer; just if you want to return back to the same position `val currentPosition = viewPager.currentItem
viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition, false)`

Answer (score 4):

```
public class DayFlipper extends ViewPager {

private Flipperadapter adapter;
public class FlipperAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return DayFlipper.DAY_HISTORY;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View container) {
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "instantiateItem(): " + position);

        Date d = DateHelper.getBot();
        for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            d = DateHelper.getTomorrow(d);
        }

        d = DateHelper.normalize(d);

        CubbiesView cv = new CubbiesView(mContext);
        cv.setLifeDate(d);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(cv, 0);
        // add map
        cv.setCubbieMap(mMap);
        cv.initEntries(d);
adpter = FlipperAdapter.this;
        return cv;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((CubbiesView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View container) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((CubbiesView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {

    }

}

    ...

    public void refresh() {
    adapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

try this.

Comment: This does not work for me. Just to be sure that we are on same page. I have selected one of x pages that are available to scroll through in `ViewPager`. From menu I invoke action that somehow process data in underlying db and change it. On that page I am presenting that data. By process that I triggered in menu that data were changed. So this change I want to reflect to page I am looking at. It is reflected if I scroll 2 pages out from my current and then return to actual because `instantiateItem()` is triggered but I want to do this without scrolling.

Comment: Overriding instantiateItem() is great for if you delete a fragment and then want to add it back. I found this useful for another problem I was having, however not for this one.