# Switching between two ViewPager contents

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-support-library

In my app I have the dropdown enabled in the ActionBar. The user has two elements to choose from. Depending on the choice I want a ViewPager to show different contents from different FragmentPagerAdapters. The user has to have the ability to switch all the time.

I've tried to set two different PagerAdapters in the listener with no luck. The Pager would just reload the previous fragments every time. Similar problems are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view/7287121#7287121) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369978/how-to-force-viewpager-to-re-instantiate-its-items). However in my approach I don't want to change the content of one adapter. I really just want to switch between two separate adapters.

This whole thing seems really confusing to me. Are there any known workaround for this or is there an alternative solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible for your application, I would suggest using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Each adapter should be able to store a separate list of fragments, and should keep the saved state of your fragments when you switch to the other adapter.

Comment: Great. Switching the Superclass of my Adapters to FragmentStatePagerAdapter made it work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried to set two different PagerAdapters in the listener with no luck. The Pager would just reload the previous fragments every time.

I am assuming that you are using `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Both of those store their fragments by tag name in the `FragmentManager`, and therefore this switching approach will not work.

> Are there any known workaround for this or is there an alternative solution to my problem?

One approach would be to fork `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, replacing the `makeFragmentName()` method to use an alternative tag syntax, and use the revised adapter class for one of your two.

Comment: I think you may be wrong about `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` storing fragments by tag names. Instead, it just keeps all active fragments in an `ArrayList`.