# Android ViewPager not updated

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have `ViewPager` with one page and `Tab's`.  In `AsyncTask` i load data, and update `ViewPager`, but nothing change. In LogCat i checked, i have needed data.

**MainClass.java**

```
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.cinema_view_pager);
    mTabPager = new TabPager("Загрузка");
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mTabPager);

    LoadCinema cinema = new LoadCinema(this,0);
    cinema.execute();
```

**TabPager(Adapter).class**

```
public class TabPager extends PagerAdapter{

    private String message = "";

    public TabPager(String msg){
        message = msg;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    public void update(String msg){
        message = msg;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(View container, int position){
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cinema_layout, null);

        TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText(message+"Message" +"");

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(v);
        return v;           
    }

    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

}
```

**LoadCinema.class**

```
public void onPostExecute(List<CinemaCategory> result){
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    CinemaCategory cat = result.get(page);  
    cinema.mTabPager.update(cat.getDescription());
}
```

I tryed with three pages, and when i swype to last page, i haved data and then swype to first page view pager updated.

Comment: post the source of 'mTabPager'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now i have Answer, Thank's to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369978/how-to-force-viewpager-to-re-instantiate-its-items)

To adapter need add this code

```
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
           return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

Comment: when i refresh the viewpagers data, first two view pagers are not refresh and other view pager data is changing. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `PagerAdapter`

```
public class TabPager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

...

}
```