# Clearing OffscreenPage in Android ViewPager

Tags: android, android-tabs, viewpage

I have a ViewPager and multiple tabs.
One of these tabs controls the settings, which affects every other tabs.
Everything updates itself perfectly fine when I change the settings, except for the pages that are kept in memory.  In order to get these to update I have to select a tab far enough from it, then come back.

Is there a way to force these tabs to recreate themselves?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369978/how-to-force-viewpager-to-re-instantiate-its-items) on SO, you can reset the adapter which will reload all the pages:

```
viewPage.setAdapter( adapter );
```

[The duplicate that that question is linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view) also gives some helpful information, such as calling `.notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `ViewPager` adapter.