# ViewPager PageAdapter not updating View

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Okay, the problem is almost the same with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291), but the solution there didn't solve my problem.

I use `FragmentPagerAdapter` with a `List` holding the `Fragment`s like the below shown.

```
public class ViewPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    ...
}
```

And my `Fragment` overrides the onCreateView method like this.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedState) {
    return inflater.inflate(theLayoutResourceId, container, false);
}
```

If using the method in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291) (override `int getItemPosition(Object object)` to return `POSITION_NONE`), I'll get 
`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` after calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

The method call flow is like this.

1. at `ViewPager` page index 1, open a `Dialog` via clicking a `Button` (just the same as the `LoginButton` in the Facebook Android example)
2. after the dialog closed (`onAuthSucceed`), remove `ViewPager` page index 1 and and add another page to be page index 1
3. force update using `notifyDataSetChanged`

I've tried many other ways to remove a `Fragment` before adding a `Fragment` to the adapter, but the page will not update to the new content.

I just found one method to make the page blank...

```
viewpager.removeViewAt(1);
viewpagerAdapter.removeItem(1);
viewpagerAdapter.addItem(1, new Fragment(...));
```

Either solving the updating problem or `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` would be great. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: hello. could you find a solution for that problem? I have the exact same problem but can't find any working solution for me :( please help if you have something which works! thank you :)

Comment: No, I didn't solve the problem, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post is kind of old, but in case anyone runs into this. I found the answer in a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849552/android-viewpager-cant-update-dynamically?lq=1). It looks like you are on the right track but you need to change your FragmentPagerAdapter to a FragmentStatePagerAdapter and override the getItemPosition(Object), as you suggested in your post.

Best of luck to you.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried your method and it did worked, but it is still sometimes weird. I think it is because I'm trying to remove the current viewable page, and the behavior depends on the position of the current page. I think it might be solved by switching the current page out of the screen before removing it but I haven't tried it.