# Update ViewPager dynamically?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I can't update the content in ViewPager.

What is the correct usage of methods instantiateItem() and getItem() in FragmentPagerAdapter class?

I was using only getItem() to instantiate and return my fragments:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return new MyFragment(context, paramters);
}
```

This worked well. Except I can't change the content.

So I found this: [ViewPager PagerAdapter not updating the View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view)

> "My approach is to use the setTag() method for any instantiated view in the instantiateItem() method"

Now I want to implement instantiateItem() to do that. But I don't know what I have to return (the type is Object) and what is the relation with getItem(int position)?

I read the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html):

> - public abstract Fragment getItem (int position)
>
>   Return the Fragment associated with a specified position.
> - public Object instantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position)
>
>   Create the page for the given position. The adapter is responsible for adding the view to the container given here, although it only must ensure this is done by the time it returns from finishUpdate(ViewGroup).
>     Parameters
>
>   container   The containing View in which the page will be shown.
>     position    The page position to be instantiated.
>
>   Returns
>
>   Returns an Object representing the new page. This does not need to be a View, but can be some other container of the page.

but I still don't get it.

Here's my code. I'm using support package v4.

ViewPagerTest

```
public class ViewPagerTest extends FragmentActivity {
    private ViewPager pager;
    private MyFragmentAdapter adapter; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pager1);

        pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.slider);

        String[] data = {"page1", "page2", "page3", "page4", "page5", "page6"};

        adapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 6, this, data);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                reload();
            }
        });
    }

    private void reload() {
        String[] data = {"changed1", "changed2", "changed3", "changed4", "changed5", "changed6"};
        //adapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 6, this, data);
        adapter.setData(data);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        pager.invalidate();

        //pager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
}
```

MyFragmentAdapter

```
class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private int slideCount;
    private Context context;
    private String[] data;

    public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int slideCount, Context context, String[] data) {
        super(fm);
        this.slideCount = slideCount;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new MyFragment(data[position], context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return slideCount;
    }

    public void setData(String[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

MyFragment

```
public final class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private String text;

    public MyFragment(String text, Context context) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide, null);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(text);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is also somebody with a similar problem, no answers
http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg200477.html

Comment: To get a better understanding of the components involved it might help to read my tutorial about a tabbed ViewPager with separate back navigation history. It comes with a working example on GitHub and additional resources: https://medium.com/@nilan/separate-back-navigation-for-a-tabbed-view-pager-in-android-459859f607e4

Comment: got some issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149039/viewpager-recyclerview-issue

Comment: You can check this [example in GitHub](https://github.com/thedeveloperworldisyours/RefreshCurrentFragmentWithinViewPager). I hope this example helps you.

Comment: Good simple solution: stackoverflow.com/a/35450575/2162226

Comment: Google recently introduced ViewPager2 which simplifies dynamic Fragment/View updates. You can see exemples on https://github.com/googlesamples/android-viewpager2 or this answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/57393414/1333448

Answer (score 626, accepted):

When using FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter, it is best to deal solely with `getItem()` and not touch `instantiateItem()` at all. The `instantiateItem()`-`destroyItem()`-`isViewFromObject()` interface on PagerAdapter is a lower-level interface that FragmentPagerAdapter uses to implement the much simpler `getItem()` interface.

Before getting into this, I should clarify that

> **if you want to switch out the actual fragments that are being displayed, you need to avoid FragmentPagerAdapter and use
>   FragmentStatePagerAdapter.**

An earlier version of this answer made the mistake of using FragmentPagerAdapter for its example - that won't work because FragmentPagerAdapter never destroys a fragment after it's been displayed the first time.

I don't recommend the `setTag()` and `findViewWithTag()` workaround provided in the post you linked. As you've discovered, using `setTag()` and `findViewWithTag()` doesn't work with fragments, so it's not a good match.

The right solution is to override `getItemPosition()`. When `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called, ViewPager calls `getItemPosition()` on all the items in its adapter to see whether they need to be moved to a different position or removed.

By default, `getItemPosition()` returns `POSITION_UNCHANGED`, which means, "This object is fine where it is, don't destroy or remove it." Returning `POSITION_NONE` fixes the problem by instead saying, "This object is no longer an item I'm displaying, remove it." So it has the effect of removing and recreating every single item in your adapter.

This is a completely legitimate fix! This fix makes notifyDataSetChanged behave like a regular Adapter without view recycling. If you implement this fix and performance is satisfactory, you're off to the races. Job done.

If you need better performance, you can use a fancier `getItemPosition()` implementation. Here's an example for a pager creating fragments off of a list of strings:

```
ViewPager pager = /* get my ViewPager */;
// assume this actually has stuff in it
final ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
pager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
    public int getCount() {
        return titles.size();
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        fragment.setTitle(titles.get(position));
        return fragment;
    }

    public int getItemPosition(Object item) {
        MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment)item;
        String title = fragment.getTitle();
        int position = titles.indexOf(title);

        if (position >= 0) {
            return position;
        } else {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }
});
```

With this implementation, only fragments displaying new titles will get displayed. Any fragments displaying titles that are still in the list will instead be moved around to their new position in the list, and fragments with titles that are no longer in the list at all will be destroyed.

What if the fragment has not been recreated, but needs to be updated anyway? Updates to a living fragment are best handled by the fragment itself. That's the advantage of having a fragment, after all - it is its own controller. A fragment can add a listener or an observer to another object in `onCreate()`, and then remove it in `onDestroy()`, thus managing the updates itself. You don't have to put all the update code inside `getItem()` like you do in an adapter for a ListView or other AdapterView types.

One last thing - just because FragmentPagerAdapter doesn't destroy a fragment doesn't mean that getItemPosition is completely useless in a FragmentPagerAdapter. You can still use this callback to reorder your fragments in the ViewPager. It will never remove them completely from the FragmentManager, though.

Comment: Doesn't work, it's still not updating anything... posted my code.

Comment: Okay, figured out the problem - you need to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter rather than FragmentPagerAdapter. FragmentPagerAdapter never removes fragments from the FragmentManager, it only detaches and attaches them. Check the docs for more info - in general, you only want to use FragmentPagerAdapter for fragments that are permanent. I've edited my example with the correction.

Comment: I will review this at some point later... thanks for your answer. And then I accept your answer if it works. Before your last comment I implemented to remove and add a new ViewPager each time and that works. Not very good solution, but I don't have time now to change it.

Comment: You're right, changing the class of the adapter to FragmentStatePagerAdapter fixed all my trouble. Thanks!

Comment: i've tried your nice answer but it doesn't solve my issue , my problem is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117981/refreshing-views-of-fragments-inside-of-a-viewpager

Comment: -Bill Phillips i am new to android , can you provide a same code about MyFragment class.

Comment: Hemant - MyFragment is just a placeholder class name. It would be whatever fragment class you are using in your own application.

Comment: Hey, this works for the most part.  However, I'm having trouble getting any fragment's view using a page swipe.  I have multiple ways to progress in this page swiping a 'next' button that removes that item from the adapter and notifies that adapter and updates accordingly, or swiping the page adapter (using it's native implementation).  When I swipe, I can get to the next one, but not the one after that.  It seems to not be adding the next items to the fragment manager yet. Any thoughts?

Comment: Implementing a FragmentStatePagerAdapter and overriding the getItemPosition fixed my problem of having the viewpager in my fragment which was in a tabhost not updating after removing a fragment. Cost me a day to screw around with, and your answer fixed it in minutes. Thank you!

Comment: God, thank you, this has been driving me nuts. I had tried the `FragmentStatePageAdapter` and the `getItemPosition`, but not the two together. Trying them together worked, thank you!

Comment: Hi, I've been reading all the answers in this thread however - I'm working on a viewpager that handles a bunch of list views instead of fragments. I want to update one listview every 30/60 seconds  based on the position it is in, in the view pager. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think you'll get better feedback if you submit a standalone question for that, darkravedev.

Comment: I just change the `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `FragmentStatePageAdapter `, it's working :'( you saved my life !!!

Comment: What is `MyFragment` and where to know about it, thanks!

Comment: That answer solved my issue, but I didn't get why he's getting indexOf(title) in order to return the position when we can simply use PositionUnchanged instead. Or did I misunderstand this?

Comment: PositionUnchanged would solve the problem, too, yeah. The given code will also handle the situation where items are moving around, if you need that.

Comment: @BillPhillips .. Hi can u check out my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231180/how-to-update-the-list-whenever-the-tabs-are-changing-in-view-pager ..  I tried your answer but none are working .. can you please help me out

Comment: @BillPhillips thanks a lot!!! one week of headache gone in a second!! i just used FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter! now my pages are updating and everytime view pager adapter is loading the page again!! Thank you so much! :) :)

Comment: @BillPhillips can you look at my question? It's not working. I am following your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129247/viewpager-not-getting-updated-using-fragmentstatepageradapter

Comment: Even when I return POSITION_NONE, while using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, I can see that  it removes my fragment and creates the new instance. But the new instance receives a savedInstanceState Bundle with the state of an old fragment. How can I completely destroy the fragment so Bundle is null when created again?

Comment: @BillPhillips can you help in my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149039/viewpager-recyclerview-issue

Comment: i have used this adapter but my issue is i get in correct indexes when i remove items

Comment: Ok so can someone explain to why we have all struggled so much with this and what is Google's explanation for this? The better I get at coding, the more I think some of these developers at Android are either certifiably brilliant or the exact opposite...I am leaning toward the the last option. This is so ridiculous, that is all it took to fix things and make the Adapter work the way we all seem to want it to work so why is Google so far out of touch with us App makers...baffling...

Comment: Can confirm what @Singed said - the new instance of the fragment receives an old saved state. Not working as expected.

Comment: Solution - create a new adapter each time you need to completely swap the items.

Comment: https://medium.com/bazaar-tech/dynamically-update-refresh-reload-viewpager2-fragments-588fcbd6f859

Answer (score 149):

Instead of returning `POSITION_NONE` from `getItemPosition()` and causing full view recreation, do this:

```
//call this method to update fragments in ViewPager dynamically
public void update(UpdateData xyzData) {
    this.updateData = xyzData;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof UpdateableFragment) {
        ((UpdateableFragment) object).update(updateData);
    }
    //don't return POSITION_NONE, avoid fragment recreation. 
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}
```

Your fragments should implement `UpdateableFragment` interface:

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment implements
    UpdateableFragment{

    @Override
    public void update(UpdateData xyzData) {
         // this method will be called for every fragment in viewpager
         // so check if update is for this fragment
         if(forMe(xyzData)) {
           // do whatever you want to update your UI
         }
    }
}
```

and the interface:

```
public interface UpdateableFragment {
   public void update(UpdateData xyzData);
}
```

Your data class:

```
public class UpdateData {
    //whatever you want here
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that your MainActivity also needs to implement the interface ??? Please help me out here. In my current implementation, I am using my MainActivity class as a communicator between the fragments, so I was confused about this solution.

Comment: Ok I have answered at another place with full implementation where I am updating `Fragment` dynamically, have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891828/scroll-all-the-listview-in-a-viewpager/20089116#20089116

Comment: @M-WaJeEh maybe some example please!!! i have a listview with list of cities and after selecting city opens viewpager (3 pages) with information about this city. it works ok. but after selecting another city viewpager shows only the 3`d page on refreshes the 1-st page only after swiping pages? thw 2`d page is always blank. thanks

Comment: @SERG Here is a full working example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891828/synchronize-all-the-listview-in-a-viewpager/20089116#20089116

Comment: among all the stuff i ve seen for the past 2.5 days of my work life.. this is the only one that worked for me.. all sorts of arigato, thanks, spaciba, sukran .. n.

Comment: Mother of Dragons!, this works like a charm, the only solution worked for me... thx a lot !!

Comment: It make some consequences in another fragment in the same view pager! Did anyone notice that? I am using fragmentstatepageradapter. When i do the above the another fragment data is null.

Comment: @RethinavelPillai You are supposed to put some information in `UpdateData` which then can be used to discard update inside fragment.

Comment: Any idea on mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40095826/how-to-update-a-fragment-that-has-a-gridview-populated-from-sqlite

Comment: It worked for me until Support library 25.1.0 came out. Now it no longer works. .( Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Hi, can you please suggest same approach for PagerAdapter ? I dont have fragments, just activity and viewpager with PagerAdapter.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh can you tell me what is UpdateData?

Comment: @M-WaJeEh we can not declare main static class we just write static classes inner main class means child classes can be static in Android

Comment: I was assuming that you would put it inside your `BaseFragment` or whatever. Anyways updated my answer to make it just a class.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh  I have four fragments that load through one actvity using tablayout and viewpager and i confused add this class in where

Comment: @M-WaJeEh Your way is very nice! The update is slow in my case. Have you got that problem? The old data appears before being replaced.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh Hey what if i want to delete an view from view pager in same way as you mentioned ? Can you please help me out ? It shows blank page after removing an view and then not able to swipe.

Comment: https://medium.com/bazaar-tech/dynamically-update-refresh-reload-viewpager2-fragments-588fcbd6f859

Answer (score 29):

for those who still face the same problem which i faced before when i have a `ViewPager` with 7 fragments. the default for these fragments to load the English content from `API` service but the problem here that i want to change the language from settings activity and after finish 
settings activity i want `ViewPager` in main activity to refresh the fragments to match the language selection from the user and load the Arabic content if user chooses Arabic here what i did to work from the first time

**1- You must use FragmentStatePagerAdapter as mentioned above.**

2- on mainActivity i override the onResume and did the following

```
if (!(mPagerAdapter == null)) {
    mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

3-i overrided the `getItemPosition()` in mPagerAdapter and make it return `POSITION_NONE`.

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

works like charm

Comment: Works except in one situtaion. When you delete last item in viewPager. Then it doesn't remove from list.

Comment: I was adding fragments to both the left and right side of the current fragment in the viewpager dynamatically. This one worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

I have encountered this problem and finally solved it today, so I write down what I have learned and I hope it is helpful for someone who is new to Android's `ViewPager` and update as I do. I'm using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` in API level 17 and currently have just 2 fragments. I think there must be something not correct, please correct me, thanks.
[image]

1. Serialized data has to be loaded into memory. This can be done using a `CursorLoader`/`AsyncTask`/`Thread`. Whether it's automatically loaded depends on your code. If you are using a `CursorLoader`, it's auto-loaded since there is a registered data observer.
2. After you call `viewpager.setAdapter(pageradapter)`, the adapter's `getCount()` is constantly called to build fragments. So if data is being loaded, `getCount()` can return 0, thus you don't need to create dummy fragments for no data shown.
3. After the data is loaded, the adapter will not build fragments automatically since `getCount()` is still 0, so we can set the actually loaded data number to be returned by `getCount()`, then call the adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()`. `ViewPager` begin to create fragments (just the first 2 fragments) by data in memory. It's done before `notifyDataSetChanged()` is returned. Then the `ViewPager` has the right fragments you need.
4. If the data in the database and memory are both updated (write through), or just data in memory is updated (write back), or only data in the database is updated. In the last two cases if data is not automatically loaded from the database to memory (as mentioned above).
   The `ViewPager` and pager adapter just deal with data in memory.
5. So when data in memory is updated, we just need to call the adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Since the fragment is already created, the adapter's `onItemPosition()` will be called before `notifyDataSetChanged(）` returns. Nothing needs to be done in `getItemPosition()`. Then the data is updated.

Comment: i have found the nothing need to do  after you update data(in memeory), just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` then just updated automatically,  because the fragment(with chartview) i use will refresh itself. if it's not, like a static fragment, i will have to call `onItemPositon()` and returns `POSITION_NONE`  sorry about that

Comment: Does anyone have an idea of what tool was used to make that diagram?

Answer (score 13):

Try `destroyDrawingCache()` on ViewPager after `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your code.

Comment: Same here. Works great thank you. I had especially a tough time cause I am not using `Fragments` in my view pager. So thank you!

Answer (score 11):

After hours of frustration while trying all the above solutions to overcome this problem and also trying many solutions on other similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849552/android-viewpager-cant-update-dynamically), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736953/viewpager-does-not-redraw-content-remains-turns-blank) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611018/how-to-update-viewpager-content) which all FAILED with me to solve this problem and to make the `ViewPager` to destroy the old `Fragment` and fill the `pager` with the new `Fragment`s. I have solved the problem as following:

**1)** Make the `ViewPager` class to extends `FragmentPagerAdapter` as following:

```
 public class myPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
```

**2)** Create an Item for the `ViewPager` that store the `title` and the `fragment` as following:

```
public class PagerItem {
private String mTitle;
private Fragment mFragment;


public PagerItem(String mTitle, Fragment mFragment) {
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
    this.mFragment = mFragment;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}
public Fragment getFragment() {
    return mFragment;
}
public void setTitle(String mTitle) {
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
}

public void setFragment(Fragment mFragment) {
    this.mFragment = mFragment;
}

}
```

**3)** Make the constructor of the `ViewPager` take my `FragmentManager` instance to store it in my `class` as following:

```
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private ArrayList<PagerItem> mPagerItems;

public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, ArrayList<PagerItem> pagerItems) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    mPagerItems = pagerItems;
}
```

**4)** Create a method to re-set the `adapter` data with the new data by deleting all the previous `fragment` from the `fragmentManager` itself directly to make the `adapter` to set the new `fragment` from the new list again as following:

```
public void setPagerItems(ArrayList<PagerItem> pagerItems) {
    if (mPagerItems != null)
        for (int i = 0; i < mPagerItems.size(); i++) {
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mPagerItems.get(i).getFragment()).commit();
        }
    mPagerItems = pagerItems;
}
```

**5)** From the container `Activity` or `Fragment` do not re-initialize the adapter with the new data. Set the new data through the method `setPagerItems` with the new data as following:

```
ArrayList<PagerItem> pagerItems = new ArrayList<PagerItem>();
    pagerItems.add(new PagerItem("Fragment1", new MyFragment1()));
    pagerItems.add(new PagerItem("Fragment2", new MyFragment2()));

    mPagerAdapter.setPagerItems(pagerItems);
    mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: can you help me in my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149039/viewpager-recyclerview-issue

Comment: can you please help me with this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41547995/java-lang-illegalstateexception-the-application-pageradapter-changed-the-adapte/41548210?noredirect=1#comment70327157_41548210

Answer (score 9):

For some reason none of the answers worked for me so I had to override the restoreState method without calling super in my fragmentStatePagerAdapter. Code:

```
private class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    // [Rest of implementation]

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {}

}
```

Comment: After trying everything else in this SO answer, this is the one that worked for me. I'm finish()ing an activity that's returning to the Activity that hosts the PagerAdapter in question. I want all my fragments to be re-created in this case because the Activity that I just finished may have changed the state that is used to draw the fragments.

Comment: OMG.. it works.. it works.. kudos :D 
In my case i need to remove viewpager current item object. but the current fragment is not updating after trying all the above methods/steps.

Comment: `restoreState` is marked final in later versions of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

Comment: Yeah, this answer is 6 years old. The pager stuff has improved since then.

Answer (score 3):

I slightly modified the solution provided by Bill Phillips to suit my needs

```
private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    Bundle oBundle;
    FragmentManager oFragmentManager;
    ArrayList<Fragment> oPooledFragments;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    oFragmentManager=fm;

    }
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

    Fragment oFragment=(Fragment)object;
    oPooledFragments=new ArrayList<>(oFragmentManager.getFragments());
    if(oPooledFragments.contains(oFragment))
        return POSITION_NONE;
    else
        return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
    } 
}
```

so that the `getItemPosition()` returns `POSITION_NONE` only for those fragments which are currently in the `FragmentManager` when `getItemPosition` is called.
(Note that this `FragmentStatePager` and the `ViewPager` associated with it are contained in a Fragment not in a Activity)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem but don't want to trust on the existing solutions (hard coded tag names etc.) and I couldn't make M-WaJeEh's solution work for me. Here is my solution:

I keep references to the fragments created in getItem in an array. This works fine as long as the activity is not destroyed due to configurationChange or lack of memory or whatever (--> when coming back to the activity, fragments return to their last state without 'getItem' being called again and thus without updating the array).

To avoid this problem I implemented instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int) and update my array there, like this:

```
        @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Object o = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        if(o instanceof FragmentX){
            myFragments[0] = (FragmentX)o;
        }else if(o instanceof FragmentY){
            myFragments[1] = (FragmentY)o;
        }else if(o instanceof FragmentZ){
            myFragments[2] = (FragmentZ)o;
        }
        return o;
    }
```

So, on the one hand I'm happy that I found a solution that works for me and wanted to share it with you, but I also wanted to ask whether somebody else tried something similar and whether there is any reason why I shouldn't do it like that? So far it works very good for me...

Comment: I've done something related in http://stackoverflow.com/a/23427215/954643, although you should probably remove the item from `myFragments` in `public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)` as well so you don't grab a stale fragement reference.

Answer (score 2):

I have lived same problem and I have searched too much times. Any answer given in stackoverflow or via google was not solution for my problem. My problem was easy. I have a list, I show this list with viewpager. When I add a new element to head of the list and I refresh the viewpager nothings changed. My final solution was very easy anybody can use. When a new element added to list and want to refresh the list. Firstly set viewpager adapter to null then recreate the adapter and set i to it to viewpager.

```
myVPager.setAdapter(null);
myFragmentAdapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),newList);
myVPager.setAdapter(myFragmentAdapter);
```

Be sure your adapter must extend FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Answer (score 2):

**Using `ViewPager2` and `FragmentStateAdapter`:**

Updating data dynamically is supported by `ViewPager2`.

There is an important note in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration) on how to get this working:

> Note: The `DiffUtil` utility class relies on identifying items by ID. **If you are using ViewPager2 to page through a mutable collection, you must also override `getItemId()` and `containsItem()`.** (emphasis mine)

Based on `ViewPager2` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2) and Android's Github [sample project](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/master/ViewPager2) there are a few steps we need to take:

1. Set up `FragmentStateAdapter` and override the following methods: `getItemCount`, `createFragment`, `getItemId`, and `containsItem` (note: `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is not supported by `ViewPager2`)
2. Attach adapter to `ViewPager2`
3. Dispatch list updates to `ViewPager2` with `DiffUtil` (don't need to use `DiffUtil`, as seen in sample project)

---

**Example:**

```kotlin
private val items: List<Int>
    get() = viewModel.items
private val viewPager: ViewPager2 = binding.viewPager

private val adapter = object : FragmentStateAdapter(this@Fragment) {
    override fun getItemCount() = items.size
    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment = MyFragment()
    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = items[position].id
    override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean = items.any { it.id == itemId }
}
viewPager.adapter = adapter
    
private fun onDataChanged() {
    DiffUtil
        .calculateDiff(object : DiffUtil.Callback() {
            override fun getOldListSize(): Int = viewPager.adapter.itemCount
            override fun getNewListSize(): Int = viewModel.items.size
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int) =
                viewPager.adapter?.getItemId(oldItemPosition) == viewModel.items[newItemPosition].id

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int) =
                areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition, newItemPosition)
        }, false)
        .dispatchUpdatesTo(viewPager.adapter!!)
}
```

Comment: The question is in Java why do you put a solution in Kotlin?

Comment: @Teocci is good, easy for people who use latest package to solve issue.

Answer (score 1):

I use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library to update `Fragment` content in `ViewPager`. The logic is simple, just like [document of EventBus how to do](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md). It is no need to control `FragmentPagerAdapter` instance. The code is here:

1: Define events

Define which message which is needed to update.

```
public class UpdateCountEvent {
    public final int count;

    public UpdateCountEvent(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

2.Prepare subscribers

Write below code in the Fragment which is needed update.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);  
    super.onStop();
}

public void onEvent(UpdateCountEvent event) {//get update message
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), event.count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

3.Post events

Write below code in other `Activity` or other `Fragment` which needs to update parameter

```
//input update message
EventBus.getDefault().post(new UpdateCountEvent(count));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had been trying so many different approaches, none really sove my problem. Below are how I solve it with a mix of solutions provided by you all. Thanks everyone.

```
class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public boolean flag_refresh=false;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int page) {
        FragmentsMain f;
        f=new FragmentsMain();
        f.page=page;
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object item) {
        int page= ((FragmentsMain)item).page;

        if (page == 0 && flag_refresh) {
            flag_refresh=false;
            return POSITION_NONE;
        } else {
            return super.getItemPosition(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {

        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

I only want to refresh page 0 after onResume().

```
 adapter=new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
 pager.setAdapter(adapter);

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (adapter!=null) {
        adapter.flag_refresh=true;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

In my FragmentsMain, there is public integer "page", which can tell me whether it is the page I want to refresh.

```
public class FragmentsMain extends Fragment {

private Cursor cursor;
private static Context context;
public int page=-1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter, please take a look at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=37990.
There are issues with FragmentStatePagerAdapter that may or may not trouble your use case.

Also, link has few solutions too..few may suit to your requirement.

Comment: From that URL I found solution. I used the modified FragmentStatePagerAdapter from this gist https://gist.github.com/ypresto/8c13cb88a0973d071a64 in my code and it started to work as supposed to be.

Comment: Cool. Yes. Link has few solutions too.

Answer (score 1):

I know am late for the Party. I've fixed the problem by calling `TabLayout#setupWithViewPager(myViewPager);` just after `FragmentPagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 1):

This might be of help to someone - in my case when inserting a new page the view pager was asking for the position of an existing fragment twice, but not asking for the position of the new item, causing incorrect behaviour and data not displaying.

1. Copy the source for for FragmentStatePagerAdapter (seems to have not been updated in ages).
2. Override notifyDataSetChanged()

   ```
   @Override
   public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
       mFragments.clear();
       super.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ```
3. Add a sanity check to destroyItem() to prevent crashes:

   ```
   if (position < mFragments.size()) {
       mFragments.set(position, null);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation that incorporates the info from @Bill Phillips
One gets fragment caching most of the time, except when the data has changed. Simple, and seems to work fine.

MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter.java

```
private boolean mIsUpdating = false;
public void setIsUpdating(boolean mIsUpdating) {
        this.mIsUpdating = mIsUpdating;
    }


@Override
public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {

    if (mIsUpdating) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
    else {
        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }
}
```

MyActivity.java

```
mAdapter.setIsUpdating(true);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mAdapter.setIsUpdating(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution won't work for everyone, but in my case, every Fragment in my ViewPager is a different class, and only one of them ever exist at a time.

With this constraint, this solution is safe and should be safe to use in production.

```
private void updateFragment(Item item) {

    List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {

        if (fragment instanceof MyItemFragment && fragment.isVisible()) {
            ((MyItemFragment) fragment).update(item);
        }

    }
}
```

If you have multiple versions of the same fragment, you can use this same strategy to call methods on those fragments to determine if it is the fragment you wish to update.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through all the answers above and a number of others posts but still couldn't find something that worked for me (with different fragment types along with dynamically adding and removing tabs).  FWIW following approach is what worked for me (in case anyone else has same issues).

```
public class MyFragmentStatePageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private static final String TAB1_TITLE = "Tab 1";
    private static final String TAB2_TITLE = "Tab 2";
    private static final String TAB3_TITLE = "Tab 3";

    private ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<Fragment, Integer> fragmentPositions = new HashMap<>();


    public MyFragmentStatePageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    public void update(boolean showTab1, boolean showTab2, boolean showTab3) {
        titles.clear();

        if (showTab1) {
            titles.add(TAB1_TITLE);
        }
        if (showTab2) {
            titles.add(TAB2_TITLE);
        }
        if (showTab3) {
            titles.add(TAB3_TITLE);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        String tabName = titles.get(position);
        if (tabName.equals(TAB1_TITLE)) { 
            fragment =  Tab1Fragment.newInstance();
        } else if (tabName.equals(TAB2_TITLE)) {
            fragment =  Tab2Fragment.newInstance();
        } else if (tabName.equals(TAB3_TITLE)) {
            fragment =  Tab3Fragmen.newInstance();
        } 

        ((BaseFragment)fragment).setTitle(tabName);
        fragmentPositions.put(fragment, position);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object item) {
        BaseFragment fragment = (BaseFragment)item;
        String title = fragment.getTitle();
        int position = titles.indexOf(title);

        Integer fragmentPosition = fragmentPositions.get(item);
        if (fragmentPosition != null && position == fragmentPosition) {
            return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
        } else {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        fragmentPositions.remove(object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter
if you want to recreate or reload fragment on index basis 
For example if you want to reload fragment other than FirstFragment, you can check instance and return position like this

```
 public int getItemPosition(Object item) {
    if(item instanceof FirstFragment){
       return 0;
    }
    return POSITION_NONE;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need change instantiateItem's mFragments element getItemPosition.

```
    if (mFragments.size() > position) {
        Fragment f = mFragments.get(position);

        if (f != null) {
            int newPosition = getItemPosition(f);
            if (newPosition == POSITION_UNCHANGED) {
                return f;
            } else if (newPosition == POSITION_NONE) {
                mFragments.set(position, null);
            } else {
                mFragments.set(newPosition, f);
            }
        }
    }
```

Based AndroidX FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java, because `mFragments`'s elements position do not change when calling notifyDataSetChanged().

Source: 
https://github.com/cuichanghao/infivt/blob/master/library/src/main/java/cc/cuichanghao/library/FragmentStatePagerChangeableAdapter.java

Example:
https://github.com/cuichanghao/infivt/blob/master/app/src/main/java/cc/cuichanghao/infivt/MainActivityChangeablePager.kt

You can run this project to confirm how to work.
https://github.com/cuichanghao/infivt