# how to upgrade ViewPager from its pages

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I use the example of a pager [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts)

I have everything worked out but there is one problem. I have 4 different fragments. One of them contains ListView. When I click on an item in the ListView, change the global variable `guestId`. If then return to other fragments, these they should be changed. Because they use this variable as a parameter. But they do not change.

```
public class Guest extends Fragment {
...
    private ViewPager pager;
    private MyPagerAdapter adapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guest, null);

...

        if (InternetResiver.isOnline(getActivity())) {
            setData();
        } else {
            AlertDialog alert = InternetResiver.getAlertDialog(getActivity());
            alert.show();
        }
        return v;
    }

    public void startNewTread(String newId) {
        guestId = newId;
        Log.d("usernewid",newId);
        setData();
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {
                case 0: return Folio.newInstance(guestId,hotel,room);
                case 1: return BalanceDetail.newInstance(guestId,hotel);
                case 2: return History.newInstance(guestId,hotel);
                case 3: return Record.newInstance(guestId,hotel,room);
                default: return Folio.newInstance(guestId,hotel,room);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }       
    }

    public void setData() {
        String link = String.format(......., guestId, hotel);
        new MyAsincTask(getActivity()){........}.execute(link);
    }
}
```

my fragment

```
public class Folio extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<FolioBean> folioBeans;
    private TableLayout tableFolio;
    private String guestId;
    private String hotel;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.folio, null);
         guestId = getArguments().getString("guestid");
         hotel = getArguments().getString("hotel");

        folioBeans = new ArrayList<>();
        tableFolio = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tableFolio);
        if (InternetResiver.isOnline(getActivity())) {
            setData();
        } else {
            AlertDialog alert = InternetResiver.getAlertDialog(getActivity());
            alert.show();
        }
        return v;

    }

    public static Folio newInstance(String guestid,String hotel,String room) {

        Folio f = new Folio();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("guestid", guestid);
        b.putString("hotel", hotel);
        b.putString("room", room);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }

    public void setData() {
        String link = String.format(........., guestId, hotel);
        new MyAsincTask(getActivity()){........}.execute(link);
    }
}
```

other fragments are loaded using the same `guestId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because ViewPager cached fragments. You need use FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead `FragmentPagerAdapter`, and call `notifydatasetchanged()` after changing `guestId`, and override

Override getItemPosition in your PagerAdapter like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

see similar questions

[Refresh images on FragmentStatePagerAdapter on resuming activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695649/refresh-images-on-fragmentstatepageradapter-on-resuming-activity)

Comment: I had just got acquainted with the matter. and almost disappointed. but it turned out that I forgot to change the FragmentStatePagerAdapter. thank you so much! everything works!