# FragmentPagerAdapter with Cursor doesn't recall getItem after swapping the Cursor

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

I have created FragmentPagerAdapter that uses a Cursor loaded by a Loader. Everytime there's new stuff in the DB the Loader loads the Cursor into the Activity and I swap the Cursor inside the FragmentPagerAdapter and `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

However I am missing something because nothing changes since no one calls the getItem method of the Adapter again.

Basically the new Cursor contains a new record in position 0. If I am looking at position 0 I would expect a new Fragment to appear in that position.. and the rest to move to the right... right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since I was looking for FragmentPagerAdapter with Cursor I couldn't find and answer but it has actually been answered here [Update ViewPager dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849552/android-viewpager-cant-update-dynamically)