# Why cannot I detach fragment from FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, fragment, detach, fragmentpageradapter

I would like to detach a fragment from my FragmentPagerAdapter, but it doesnt seem to be working. Here is my pageradapter class, which I copied from the original code:

```
public class PagerAdapter1 extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<String> fragments;
       private static final String TAG = "FragmentPagerAdapter";
        private static final boolean DEBUG = true;
        private Fragment mCurrentPrimaryItem = null;
        private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
        private FragmentTransaction mCurTransaction = null;

    /**
     * @param fm
     * @param fragments2
     */
    public PagerAdapter1(FragmentManager fm, List<String> fragments2) {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentManager=fm;
        this.fragments = fragments2;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
     */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //return this.fragments.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(ViewPagerActivity.context, fragments.get(position));

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }



      /**
     * Return the Fragment associated with a specified position.
     */


    @Override
    public void startUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
       Log.i("asasd", "asdasdasdasdasd");

        if (mCurTransaction == null) {
            mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        }

        final long itemId = getItemId(position);

        // Do we already have this fragment?
        String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId);

        Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
        if (fragment != null) {
            if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Attaching item #" + itemId + ": f=" + fragment);
                mCurTransaction.attach(fragment);

        } else {

            fragment = getItem(position);
            if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Adding item #" + itemId + ": f=" + fragment);
            mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment,
                    makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId));
          //  Log.i("asdJANIANI", " " + getFragmentTag(container.getId(),0));
            //Log.i("JANI", " " + getItem(0));
        }

        if (fragment != mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
            fragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
            fragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
        }
        **destroyItem(container,0,getItem(0));**

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        if (mCurTransaction == null) {
            mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        }
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Detaching item #" + getItemId(position) + ": f=" + object
                + " v=" + ((Fragment)object).getView());
        mCurTransaction.detach((Fragment)object);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment)object;
        if (fragment != mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
            if (mCurrentPrimaryItem != null) {
                mCurrentPrimaryItem.setMenuVisibility(false);
                mCurrentPrimaryItem.setUserVisibleHint(false);
            }
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragment.setMenuVisibility(true);
                fragment.setUserVisibleHint(true);
            }
            mCurrentPrimaryItem = fragment;
        }

        if (position == 0){
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
        if (mCurTransaction != null) {
            mCurTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            mCurTransaction = null;
            mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return ((Fragment)object).getView() == view;
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    /**
     * Return a unique identifier for the item at the given position.
     *
     * <p>The default implementation returns the given position.
     * Subclasses should override this method if the positions of items can change.</p>
     *
     * @param position Position within this adapter
     * @return Unique identifier for the item at position
     */
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, long id) {
        return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + id;
    }


}
```

I changed only one thing, I implemented a `destroyItem()` method in the instantiateItem() method, since I want to detach the fragment (position 0) everytime I instantiate a fragment. I dont get any error, it just doesnt get detached. Why?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to completely remove the fragment?

Comment: I will use it later, so I do not want to remove it completely.

Answer (score 2):

This had me busy for two days straight. I finally found the answer here:

[Update ViewPager dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849552/android-viewpager-cant-update-dynamically)

Basically, don't use a FragmentPagerAdapter, but use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter and override the getItemPosition() method. Turns out the former doesn't allow for proper changes in it's datasource and won't reflect them.

This damn bug cost me loads of time :( But the above link helped me fix it in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

In the source of `FragmentPagerAdapter.java`,

```
82  @Override
83  public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
84      if (mCurTransaction == null) {
85          mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
86      }
88      // Do we already have this fragment?
89      String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), position);
90      Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
91      if (fragment != null) {
92          if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Attaching item #" + position + ": f=" + fragment);
93          mCurTransaction.attach(fragment);
94      } else {
95          fragment = getItem(position);
96          if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Adding item #" + position + ": f=" + fragment);
97          mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment,
98                  makeFragmentName(container.getId(), position));
99      }
100      if (fragment != mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
101          fragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
102          fragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
103      }
105      return fragment;
106  }
108  @Override
109  public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
110      if (mCurTransaction == null) {
111          mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
112      }
113      if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Detaching item #" + position + ": f=" + object
114              + " v=" + ((Fragment)object).getView());
115      mCurTransaction.detach((Fragment)object);
116  }
```

You can see that it uses attach/detach to show/hide fragments. That's why they don't work.