# How to refresh fragment in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I Have 4 Fragments in 1 Activity. I need to make sure that on every fragment change the fragment is refreshed because I load JSON Data in every fragment. I use FragmentPager Adapter and RecyclerView to Show Data

This is my Adapter ( SickAdapter.java ) the code :

```
public class SickAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    private static final String TAG = SickAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = 4;

    public SickAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new SickFragmentToAll();
            case 1:
                return new SickFragmentToPending();
            case 2:
                return new SickFragmentToApproved();
            case 3:
                return new SickFragmentToDenied();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return FRAGMENT_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return "All";
            case 1:
                return "Pending";
            case 2:
                return "Approved";
            case 3:
                return "Denied";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In my Class ( SickClass.java ) I create SickClass and I Call SickAdapter, I explode them, and this is my Code :

```
public class SickClass extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = SickClass.class.getSimpleName();

    private SickAdapter mAdapter;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;


    public SickClass() {
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.employee_leave_class, container, false);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        if(mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new SickAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(new SickAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for reload your fragment;

```
  FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ft.detach(YOUR_FRAGMENT_NAME.this).attach(YOUR_FRAGMENT_NAME.this).commit();
```

Comment: In Fragment class, where you want to reload

Comment: can you give me example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startActivityForResult()` to get the result from the activity.

**References:**

[ViewPager PagerAdapter not updating the View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view)

[How to refresh a Fragment of a FragmentPagerAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709894/how-to-refresh-a-fragment-of-a-fragmentpageradapter)