# Android: findFragmentById returning null

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I am using a ViewPager with my own PagerAdapter (Note: Not using FragmentPagerAdapter). I am trying to communicate with my fragments via my Activity, but when I try and get a reference to the fragment it always returns null.

Here is my instantiate method in my custom PagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = null;

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.left, container, false);
        break;
    case 1:
        itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.middle, container, false);
        break;
    case 2:
        itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.right, container, false);
        break;
    case 3:
        itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.right_right, container, false);
        break;
    }

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}
```

Here is my xml for middle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.example.testtabswipe.MiddleFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</fragment>
```

Here is my xml for my MiddleFragment class (filenmae: middle_fragment.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/middle_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff555" >


    <TextView 
        android:text="Testing some text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:numColumns="2" 
        android:background="#fbb111" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally, this is what I'm calling in my Activity to get a reference to the Fragment:

```
MiddleFragment middleFragment = (MiddleFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.middle_fragment);
if(middleFragment == null)
    Log.d("Karl", "middleFragment Fragment null");
else
    Log.d("Karl", "middleFragment Fragment is not null");
```

It always results in "middleFragment Fragment null"

Any ideas?

**PS: This is affecting all fragments not just middle.**

Answer (score 0):

Please look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17855730/1112882) for communicating with `Fragment`s inside `ViewPager`. The idea is to set new data in adapter that you want to send to `Fragment`s and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` which in turn will call `getItemPosition()`. From where you will get reference to `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof UpdateableFragment) {
        ((UpdateableFragment) object).update(xyzData);
    }
    //don't return POSITION_NONE, avoid fragment recreation. 
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}
```