# Cannot swap the fragments displayed in a ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm changing the navigation of an app to work in as follows: the app will contain a single activity which initially shows a `ViewPager` with three views (fragments), and in one of the views there is a button which replaces these fragments with two other fragments.

I found out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852046/3704615) that I cannot use `FragmentPagerAdapter` because it never destroys a fragment after having displayed it for the first time; as I wish to swap the fragments, I will have to use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` while being sure to always return a new fragment instance in the method `getItem(int position)`. However, for the `ViewPager` to effectively update the views after changing the adapter bound to it (actually I don't change the adapter, only the data associated to it, which I use to instantiate the fragments), I must override the method `getItemPosition(Object object)` for it to return `POSITION_NONE` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the adapter. However, the views are not being updated after that process (and that is exactly my problem).

My code follows:

**ConfiguracoesDeItemDoViewPager.java (contains the data necessary for the adapter to instantiate a new fragment):**

```
public static class ConfiguracoesDeItemDoViewPager {

    private String nomeDaAba;
    private Class<? extends FragmentoBase> classeDoFragmento;
    private Bundle argumentosDoFragmento;

    public ConfiguracoesDeItemDoViewPager(String nomeDaAba, Class<? extends FragmentoBase> classeDoFragmento, Bundle argumentosDoFragmento) {
        this.nomeDaAba = nomeDaAba;
        this.classeDoFragmento = classeDoFragmento;
        this.argumentosDoFragmento = argumentosDoFragmento;
    }

    public String getNomeDaAba() {
        return nomeDaAba;
    }

    public void setNomeDaAba(String nomeDaAba) {
        this.nomeDaAba = nomeDaAba;
    }

    public Class<? extends FragmentoBase> getClasseDoFragmento() {
        return classeDoFragmento;
    }

    public void setClasseDoFragmento(
            Class<? extends FragmentoBase> classeDoFragmento) {
        this.classeDoFragmento = classeDoFragmento;
    }

    public Bundle getArgumentosDoFragmento() {
        return argumentosDoFragmento;
    }

    public void setArgumentosDoFragmento(Bundle argumentosDoFragmento) {
        this.argumentosDoFragmento = argumentosDoFragmento;
    }
}
```

**Constantes.java (provides the data to configure a ViewPager with a set of fragments):**

```
public class Constantes {

    public static final ConfiguracoesDeItemDoViewPager [] CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_1;
    public static final ConfiguracoesDeItemDoViewPager [] CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_2;

    // Bloco de inicialização de valores estáticos 
    static {
        CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_1 = new DadosDeItemDoViewPager[3];
        CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_1[0] = new DadosDeItemDoViewPager("Aba 1", FragmentoA.class, null);
        CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_1[1] = new DadosDeItemDoViewPager("Aba 2", FragmentoB.class, null);
        CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_1[2] = new DadosDeItemDoViewPager("Aba 3", FragmentoC.class, null);

        CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_2 = new DadosDeItemDoViewPager[2];
        CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_2[0] = new DadosDeItemDoViewPager("Aba 1", FragmentoD.class, null);
        CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_2[1] = new DadosDeItemDoViewPager("Aba 2", FragmentoE.class, null);
    }

...

}
```

**AtividadePrincipal.java (the only activity in the app, having the inner class for a FragmentStatePagerAdapter):**

```
public class AtividadePrincipal extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mTabsPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mTabsPagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Constantes.CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_1);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mTabsPagerAdapter);
    }

    public void exibirViewPager2() {
        ((TabsPagerAdapter)mViewPager.getAdapter()).setConfiguracoesParaInicializarViewPager(Constantes.CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_2);
    }

    public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private FragmentManager mFragmentManager; 
        private ConfiguracoesDeItemDoViewPager [] mConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager;

        public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager [] configuracoesDeItensDoViewPager) {
            super(fm);
            this.mFragmentManager = fm;
            this.mConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager = configuracoesDeItensDoViewPager;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int indice) {

            Fragment fragmento = null;

            try {
                fragmento = mConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager[indice].getClasseDoFragmento().newInstance();
                if (mConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager[indice].getArgumentosDoFragmento() != null) {
                    fragmento.setArguments(mConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager[indice].getArgumentosDoFragmento());
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                Log.e(Logs.gerarTagParaFiltragemNoLogCat(AtividadePrincipal.this, this), "Exceção inesperada!", e); 
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                Log.e(Logs.gerarTagParaFiltragemNoLogCat(AtividadePrincipal.this, this), "Exceção inesperada!", e); 
            }
            return fragmento;
        }    

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int posicao) {
           return mConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager[posicao].getNomeDaAba();
        }

        public void setConfiguracoesParaInicializarViewPager(ConfiguracoesDeItemDoViewPager [] configuracoes) {
            // Remove um fragmento extra contido dentro do FragmentoB, que se for
            // deixado no FragmentManager causa erro de id duplicado
            FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Fragment fragmento = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapa);
            if (fragmento != null && fragmento instanceof SupportMapFragment) {
                ft.remove(fragmento);
            }
            ft.commit();

            this.mConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager = configuracoes;

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Just to complete the explanation: when the use clicks a button in one of the fragments, the 
method `AtividadePrincipal.exibirViewPager2()` is called. It is supposed to update the `ViewPager` views/fragments, which doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this and it recreates/reloads the fragment (onCreate is called). In your `AtividadePrincipal.exibirViewPager2()` method add this line.

```
    this.mViewPager.setAdapter(mTabsPagerAdapter);
```

Comment: Actually calling this line a second time is not necessary since the adapter reference `mTabsPagerAdapter` is kept unchanged. But I found out what the error was -- a typo in the original code that made `CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_2` point to `CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_1` so the views would appear to be unchanged. Since you mentioned the fragment is recreated, your answer helped me to figure out the error and I am willing to accept it for your effort. Please mention what the actual fix was in the answer if you don't mind. Thanks!

Comment: Not really a fix, but I just found that setting the adapter again for the viewpager reloads the whole viewpager, thus if some data has changed it will load the viewpager with the new data

Comment: As you certainly know, that's what `notifyDataSetChanged()` is for. :)

Comment: yes but I have found that `notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't always work as expected, I tried updating a few listviews in my apps but it refused to change, So I had to come up with my own custom methods. I thought you had a similar issue.