# FragmentStatePagerAdapter does not handle changes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am having a problem managing a changing list of item using the FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Please check source [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java).

The problem is that when the underlying list changes, and I call `notifyDataSetChanged`, the adapter does not rebuild it's internal list of fragments. Referring to the code in `instantiateItem`:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    // If we already have this item instantiated, there is nothing
    // to do.  This can happen when we are restoring the entire pager
    // from its saved state, where the fragment manager has already
    // taken care of restoring the fragments we previously had instantiated.
    if (mFragments.size() > position) {
        Fragment f = mFragments.get(position);
        if (f != null) {
            return f;
        }
    }
```

I believe the code in this comment is wrong! If I delete the item at position 0 in the list, and I call `notifyDataSetChanged`, then the fragment at position 0 should be deleted. However the adapter has never updated the position of fragments in its own private list. Therefore it still shows the old, deleted, data.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849552/android-viewpager-cant-update-dynamically#17855730) but it is a hack that relies on getItemPosition being called and then forcing the fragment to update it's views.

How is it possible to manage fragments in a changing list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [ViewPager.dataSetChanged() source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#847), it uses [PagerAdapter.getItemPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getItemPosition(java.lang.Object)) to determine the new position of a item after a data change. By default, `getItemPosition()` always returns [POSITION_UNCHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#POSITION_UNCHANGED), meaning it never destroys and recreates items it has already created.

Override `getItemPosition()` to return the correct value if you want to update Fragments that already exist in response to a `notifyDataSetChanged()` call. For example, always returning [POSITION_NONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#POSITION_NONE) will always destroy every Fragment and recreate them from scratch (which, in most cases, is more work than needs to be done if items are just reordering).

Comment: Even always returning POSITION_NONE does not fix the issue I'm describing, since the internal list of fragments mFragments still holds the old fragment in the old position.

Comment: No, if you use `POSITION_NONE` then `destroyItem` is called and `mFragments.get(position)` returns `null` and we instantiate a new instance.

Comment: Ian, I have constructed a simple example which reproduces the problem. I was hoping you could take a look. Notice how you can swipe through the 4 pages. However, then go to page 1, press Delete on action bar, then swipe to the right - page is blank. Then swipe  to the end and back to the beginning - app crashes. Perhaps I am doing something wrong, but I cant see what is would be. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31143706/testapp.zip

Comment: I cant get my simple example to work. I am sure this is a bug. I will submit the bug report.

Comment: I took a look at the app you sent: always returning `POSITION_NONE` at least got it working of sorts, but there is definitely something odd going on when using the correct implementation of `getItemPosition`