# Android - Refresh viewpager content

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have an Activity with 2 fragments, which I want to refresh by the click of a button that resides on the ActionBar Toolbar.

I know there are many answers to this questions on stackoverflow which I have tried and which doesn't exactly solve my issue or looked quite complex for me to implement.

I tried using

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) viewPager.getParent();
if (parent != null) {
            parent.removeView(viewPager);
}
```

to remove viewpager and when refresh button clicked, It didnt work.

I tried `notifyDataChanged();` , It didn't work as well.

This is my Activity, FragmentPagerAdapter code below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    int firstrun = 0;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        if (viewPager != null) {
            setupViewPager(viewPager, 0);
            viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        }

        SlidingTabLayout mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);


        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        mTabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }

        });

        mTabs.setViewPager(viewPager);



        /** buttons at toolbar, that would trigger the refresh **/
        ImageView A = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        A.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        if(v.getId() == R.id.refresh ){


            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            if (viewPager != null) {
                setupViewPager(viewPager, 1);  // Setting to 1 or 0 
                viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
            }

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Refreshing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }






    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager, int num) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new TabOneFragment(), "TAB 1");
        adapter.addFragment(new TabTwoFragment(), "TAB 2");

        // I tried this , It didn't work.
        /*ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) viewPager.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.removeView(viewPager);
        }*/


        if(num==0) {
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else{
            // I tried this, It didn't work as well
            viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    // My Fragment Pager Adapter static class
    static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
        }

    }

}
```

This is my fragment code below.

```
public class TabOneFragment extends Fragment {


    private int mPage;
    private RecyclerView view;
    private View mview;

    public static TabOneFragment newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        TabOneFragment fragment = new TabOneFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            View mview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_tabs, container, false);
            view = (RecyclerView) mview.findViewById(R.id.homelistrecyclerview);


        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().
                setEndpoint(Info.getEndpoint()).build();
        MovieApi mApi = restAdapter.create(MovieApi.class);
        mApi.getTabOneContent(new Callback<Info>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Info info, Response response) {
                Info example = info;


                view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
                view.setAdapter(new ListingAdapter(getActivity(),
                        example.getMovies(), tabId, Info.getSchedule(), example.getShowtime()));
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Log.d("RetrofitError: ", error.getLocalizedMessage());

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Layout Below.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/homelistrecyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me... What exaclty you want to refresh?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849552/update-viewpager-dynamically look this.

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you want to refresh the content of the fragment and if yes what is the content (list, grid, data source?) or what else do you want to refresh?

Comment: the content of the fragment is a Recycler view , Let me add my fragment code.

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin , please see edit. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should add this to your adapter:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```