# How to update Fragments in ViewPager after updating Adapter?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I call `loadCategory` method from different items of navigation drawer.
On the first call `ViewPager` load the correct data. But on the second call data doesn't change. ViewPager shows the old data, Please help.

Thanks in advance.

```
    private void loadCategory(int id) {
          toolbar.setTitle(categoryList[id]);
          adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
          mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("shayari",currentShayaaris[position]);
        Fragment SFragment = new ShayariFragment();
        SFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return SFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return currentShayaaris.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post all the code?

Comment: facing same issue. any update???

Answer (score 2):

If you are inside a fragment you should instantiate adapter like this

```
      adapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to update

When using `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`,

> if you want to switch out the actual fragments that are being
>   displayed, you need to avoid FragmentPagerAdapter and use
>   FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

check this link for more information.[Update ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852046/2826147)

> Override getItemPosition in your PagerAdapter

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

[second way to update viewpager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7287121/2826147)

Answer (score 1):

You might need to removeView and addView to reload your viewpager to get new changes in your loadCategory function after updating adapter.

```
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mViewPager.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.removeView(mViewPager);
            mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            parent.addView(mViewPager);
        }
```

Comment: when i call loadCategory method second time, it changes data on next to next fragment. But the current fragment still show data.

Comment: actually, you are not suppose to call the adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()); every time you want to update the adapter. You are only suppose to just remove the view, notiffyDataSetchanged and add the view back