# Update data to viewpager dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have and activity `A` where I am setting viewpager adapter. I have a fragment `MyFragmentAdapter` which extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. In `A` activity I have static method where I am getting new value which I want to pass to `MyFragmentAdapter`. My problem is that it's not getting new value even when I am calling `viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();`

**A activity**

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) childView.findViewById(R.id.contents_viewpager);
final TabLayout propertyTabsHeader = (TabLayout) childView.findViewById(R.id.title_strip);

MyFragmentAdapter PagerAdapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(tabList, getSupportFragmentManager(), data);
viewPager.setAdapter(PagerAdapter);

public static void updatePgaer(final Context mCon) {
   //here I get new data 
   viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();         
}
```

**MyFragmentAdapter**

```
MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    private MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    public MyFragmentAdapter(ArrayList<String> tabList, FragmentManager fm, String data) {
        super(fm);
        this.propertyTabs = tabList;
        this.data = data;   
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new LeagueListFragements();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle();
        bdl.putInt("location", i);
        bdl.putString("title", propertyTabs.get(i).toString());
        bdl.putSerializable("data", mydata);

        fragment.setArguments(bdl);
        listFrag.add(fragment);

        return listFrag.get(i);
    }
}
```

So when I call `updatePgaer` how can I get new data in `MyFragmentAdapter`.

i am not getting new data in fragment so that i can use interface for same .. i am getting new data in parent Activity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update ViewPager dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849552/update-viewpager-dynamically)

Comment: in my case i am getting data in parent activity not in fragmentstate