# xamarin android viewpager fragments not getting refreshed

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, android-viewpager

I'm using this sample to create a simple app, it's made by Joshep Raco (JoeRock11)

https://github.com/JoeRock11/Xamarin_DesignLibrary

I have a problem, I was working with this sample to create a tabbed app, and I found an strange behavior, when the app is starting only the fragment1 and fragment2 loads , but not the fragment3 (when I say load I mean their oncreate and oncreateview method gets triggered ).
To load the fragment3 I have to explicity click it, I thought all the fragments would get load but is not the case, don't know why, I would like to know why this happens.

Also, and this is my main problem and I dont know how to fix it, every time I click a fragment tab, I want this fragment to reaload, now seems like it just shows the instantiated fragment on memory, because it doens't triger any method of the fragment, I need to load it again, because I need to refresh its data, now it only reloads randomly. can you or anyone help me solve this please?

Thanks a lot in advance.
pd: sorry for my english, it's not my mother language.

Comment: can we get some code or viable reproducible example ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is controlled by the `Off Screen Page Limit` on the `ViewPager` control. This value defaults to 1, which basically means, the number of the pages the `ViewPager` should load at a time is 2, the page that is currently displayed, and the one off screen.

This value can be easily adjusted using the `OffscreenPageLimit` property on the `ViewPager`.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

---

If you want all `Fragments` to reload data once they are slid on to the screen, you can override `UserVisibleHint` on each `Fragment`and then check to see if the `Fragment` is visible and execute some code to reload data for that fragment:

```
public override bool UserVisibleHint {
    get {
            return base.UserVisibleHint;
        }
    set {
          base.UserVisibleHint = value;
          if (value) {
            //Fragment is visible, reload data
          }
    }
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)

---

Another approach to updating the ViewPager fragments is outlined here: [Update ViewPager dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849552/update-viewpager-dynamically/17855730#17855730)