# ActionBarSherlock + ViewPager caching more then just prev/next view

Tags: android, android-viewpager

on the page:
[onCreate called for two tabs each time one tab is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610495/oncreate-called-for-two-tabs-each-time-one-tab-is-selected)

there is explained how the ABS(actually ViewPager) is working in order for ViewPager to be able to do a scrolling. 
It is clear that at least a prev/next page need all to be created at the same time.

Would it be possible to "cache" more than just prev/next Views(Fragments), in a way:

1. I am on Page 1 and there I have a network call to fetch some data(doing this in Activity, not in Fragment - btw. is this OK?)
2. switch to Page 2, and then
3. switch to Page 3, and then
4. switch to Page 1   = Here my page is recreated (using some caching though, BUT, I do not need any recreation if possible)

So, it would be nice to cache all the pages. How to accomplish this If possible in current version (4), or this would be some new feature?

Or even better question, how to postpond/disable destroying of views?

Comment: You are talking about ViewPager, not ActionBarSherlock

Comment: Sorry for not being precise...

Comment: Do you suggest I change the question, or...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I suppose It might be useful to someone else, as pointed on website
http://storkme.org/2011/12/tabs-done-right-viewpager-and-fragments/

There is already a method which allows you to predefine number of "cached" pages the ViewPager will save from recreating.

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Thanks Jake for reminding me to do a different G search :)

Comment: The site appears to be down now

Comment: The website is down now, but it was there only to show where I got this hint from. The answer should be usable, as it points to this setOffscreenPageLimit method.