# How to update ViewPager content?

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, pager, indicator

i have this `PageAdapter` with days of the week, for each pager I have the same Layout. My problem is how update the right listView when change the day. When I change the day the Pager create a new pager and delete other, when this happened my listview point to new pager but not the current. For Example, is wedneyday and I save listview reference, when i change for Tuesday the monday pager is create and Thursday is deleted, and my reference point to last page create(monday) but I'm on tuesday.

My pageAdapter:

```
ListView lvwConfig;

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View pager, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_layout, null);
    lvwConfig = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvwConfig);
    ((ViewPager) pager).addView(v, 0);

    return v;
}
```

I want to the `ListView` always point to listview of the current item.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012056/view-pager-first-and-second-fragment-data-is-not-updating-when-data-changed-in-a

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Read this post: [PagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view)

You can implement this function in PagerAdapter:

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object){
     return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

after, you can used this function:

```
yourPagerAdapterObject.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This method is bad if you have too many views as to display. All the views are always recalculated. But in your case, for some views, it's okay.

Comment: please see the post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012056/view-pager-first-and-second-fragment-data-is-not-updating-when-data-changed-in-a

Answer (score 6):

Overriding getItemPosition in PagerAdapter is easier, but bit more inefficient.
This way, when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, the view pager will remove all views and reload them all. As so the reload effect is obtained.
There was another option that [suggested by alvarolb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view/8024557#8024557), is to `setTag()` method in `instantiateItem()` when instantiating a new view. Then instead of using `notifyDataSetChanged()`, you can use `findViewWithTag()` to find the view you want to update.