# Fragment inside a ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using a **custom viewpager** which has Listfragment's loaded with **FragmentPagerAdapter**. Each ListFragment represents a **dual panel layout**, where each list item loads some other fragments to a **framelayout**(Right Panel).

Is this a best practice?

Comment: Why **are** you **randomly** bolding **words**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android **Support Library** also now supports **nested fragments**, so you can implement nested fragment designs on Android 1.6 and higher.

To nest a fragment, simply call **getChildFragmentManager()** on the Fragment in which you want to add a fragment. This returns a FragmentManager that you can use like you normally do from the top-level activity to create fragment transactions. For example, here’s some code that adds a fragment from within an existing Fragment class:

```
Fragment videoFragment = new VideoPlayerFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.video_fragment, videoFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

simple answer is...

you cannot add fragment inside a fragment.

**UPDATE**

instead what  you can do is... use `PagerAdapter` and set the view inside which has two fragments.

**Brief**

`PagerAdapter` is parent class of `FragmentPagerAdapter` so you need to make adapter which extends the pageradapter refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view) you will have an idea,

you need to look @ the `instantiateItem`, This method is responsible to generate the view, so you need to inflate and return the view in which there are two fragments.

I don't have working example right now but you can achieve this by `PagerAdapter`