# Replace contents of tab using FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am updating an old application to a new UI using actionbar sherlock.
I have the tabs in place and am using a FragmentStatePagerAdapater and it's all working great.

However certain functionality requires on a settings change to show a different fragment in a tab.

So to make things clear it's

Tab1->Fragment 1
Tab2->Fragment 2

Change config
Tab1->Fragment 1
Tab2->Fragment 3

I added to the adapter the following

```
   public void replaceTab(int postion, String name,Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {

        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args,name);
        mTabs.set(postion,info);
        ActionBar.Tab tab = mActionBar.getTabAt(postion);
        tab.setTag(info);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

This DOES modify the contents of the tab but I have to choose another tab to the far right and then go back to it again for it to refresh.

My simple question is.... how in the replacetab function can I cause the adapter to refresh all the views?

Comment: when do you call your replaceTab method?

Comment: I call it when a user selects a certain option

Comment: Ah, been asked in a million different ways and fixed it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view