# Android viewpager add fragments dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe

i working  viewpager.i have 4 fragments and  add there fragments in viepager.but i want to add fragments dinamically

Here is my adapter

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private List<Fragment> fragments;

public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fragments.add(new FragmentBlue());


    }

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}
}
```

And here is the activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyPagerAdapter pageAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
}

}
```

how i can add fragments dynamically instead of static GetCountSize(). for more information, i want to add 10 fragments in viewpager and  each fragments background wast be different.

Comment: add new fragments to your List<Fragment> fragments variable and use notifydatasetchanged as in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view

Comment: i update my code please see iy @ Illegal Argument

Comment: Did you find solution on this? Please share if because I'm trying very hard to get the solution on this.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2). By design it [allows to modify](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#modifiable-fragments) fragments collection. You can find code sample [here](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/master/ViewPager2/app/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/integration/testapp/MutableCollectionFragmentActivity.kt).

Answer (score 0):

> By using FragmentPagerAdapter we can not achieve infinite pager view
>   functionality.For this I have written my own pager view .Here every
>   time when you swipe the page it will ask for next page /previous page
>   by passing current page as reference.So by writing your own logic in
>   getNextPage(PageView currentPage)/getPreviousPage(PageView
>   currentPage) methods you can return the respective page until it reaches end.if
>   reaches end simply return null in those methods.

[Here](https://github.com/UdaySravanK/USK_Public_Rep/tree/master/APIs/Android/USKInfiniteViewPager) you can fine that sample project.

Let me know if you face any problem while using it.

Comment: thanks ,but how i  can write code to can add button in a first fragment ,edittext in second button and etc.... P.S i updated my code please see it