# Change a textview's text in not active tabs of a ViewPager in Android

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a viewpager with swipe and tabs enabled with 3 tabs. First tab have a submit button, the other two tab have dynamic content gets loaded from internet. However, since it preloads the next tab, tab 2 wont be upated when you switch to it, only tab 3 is updated. How to manually reload the tabs or just modify the text in them from other active tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, you can tell a `ViewPager` to "refresh" its pages by using `notifyDataSetChanged()` from a `PagerAdapter`. You'll need attach this `PagerAdapter` to your `ViewPager` (much like you would attach an adapter to a `ListView`). There are reputable very in-depth answers to how this can work. I would check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8024557/394933) for more information.