# Fragments being inflated with old data, when going back to an activity that was stopped

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

Activity A has fragments. When it starts an intent to activity B, then when `B.finish()`, A executes `onCreate()` again.

But this time, even though `A.onCreate()` has a new `PacksPagerAdapter` and a new `ViewPager`, the fragments are shown with old data.

I can see that that `onCreateView()` is executed for each fragment, but it still has the old arguments since the `static newInstance()` wasn't called. Arguments are created when FragmentPagerAdapter's `getItem(position)` is called.

Here's how it's implemented -

```
public class PackActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    PacksPagerAdapter mPacksPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mPacksPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPacksPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(PACK_PAGES - 1);

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setTitle(...);
                    }
                });

    }
    ...
}

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
...
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below).
        return PackFragment.newInstance(myData);
    }
...
}

public class PackFragment extends Fragment {
...
    public static PackFragment newInstance(PackInfo pack) {
        PackFragment fragment = new PackFragment();

        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(2);
        bdl.putSerializable(EXTRA_PACK, pack);
        bdl.putInt(EXTRA_PACK_POSITION, pack.packNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(bdl);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View packView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pack_fragment, container, false);

        // this has the old argument, since newInstance(...) wasn't called      
        PackInfo pack = (PackInfo) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_PACK);
        ...

        return packView;
    }

...
}
```

Any idea why new fragments aren't being instantiated on the 2nd creation of activity A?

### Update - Activity-Fragments lifecycle

The answer is, as Tal said, is that activity is being restored, so old fragments are being reattached instead of creating new ones.

After spending a lot of time studying this, I've found that there are typically 3 scenarios for activity-fragments lifecycle. Here are the scenarios, the lifecycle and how to reload fragment's old data:

**New activity**

*Lifecycle*: onCreate() ==> onResume() ==> Fragments are created and attached

No need to reload.

**Restored activity**

*Lifecycle*: onCreate() ==> Fragments inflated with old data and reattached ==> onResume()

In onResume(), remove all fragments and create new ones, either manually or automatically using an adapter -

```
        // Remove all fragments
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        for (int i = BuildConfig.PACK_PAGES - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Fragment f = findFragmentByPosition(i);
            if (f != null)
                fragmentTransaction.remove(f);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // This will force recreation of all fragments
        viewPager.setAdapter(packsPagerAdapter);
```

**Resumed activity**

*Lifecycle*: onResume()

Same as activity restore, remove old fragments and recreate.

**Note:** Some OS versions always restores activity, even when opening a SettingsActivity for a few seconds, and other (older) versions will always resume.

Comment: can you provide more codes and more explanations to make it more clearer.

Comment: How are you handling `back` event in `B`? Are you creating a new instance of activity `A` by using intent?

Comment: Not doing anything special for the back event, Android is probably using the back stack. A is the parent activity of B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my answer will be better if you'll post the fragment transaction you commit in activity A.

not sure that you know it or not - if Activity A is re-created when it pop back from back stack - it means that it [restored from previous instance state](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

in that case, you should not perform the transaction again, because - it already happens automatically via the super.onCreate() Activity method.  in fact, if you'll perform the fragment trasaction in that case - you'll cause the same fragment  to be added twice (2 instances)

you can know if currently `onCreate()`  been called from restoring instance state by checking if `savedInstanceState` parameter is null or not.

**my assumption is that you are not checking `savedInstanceState`, and performing the transaction anyway.**

if I'm right, then the following change should fix the fragment duplication problem:

instead of:

```
public static class ActivityA extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        performFragmentTransaction();

}
```

write:

```
public static class ActivityA extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
           performFragmentTransaction();
        }
}
```

more info at - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Yes, this is a known issue when create an activity with fragments.

Answer (score 1):

When the user moves away from activity `A` to `B`, the `FragmentPagerAdapter` detaches the fragments in `A` from user interface and does not destroy the instances so that they can be reused when user returns back to `A` latter.

I'm not sure why `onCreate` of `A` is called after `B` finishes. If you don't want the old fragments to be attached to the user interface, instead you want them to be recreated, then you need to explicitly destroy them.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mPacksPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(fragmentManager);

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Remove the fragments if they already exist.
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction currentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    int count = mPacksPagerAdapter.getCount();
    for(int position = 0; position < count; position++) {
        long itemId = mPacksPagerAdapter.getItemId(position);
        // fragment name format maintained by adpater: "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + id
        String name = "android:switcher:" + mViewPager.getId() + ":" + itemId;
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
        if(fragment != null) {
            // if fragment instance exists, destroy it.
            currentTransaction.remove(fragment);
        }
    }
    // commit all the operations with state loss.
    currentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    // immediately execute the operations
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

    // Rest of your code follows here.
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this hacky way, it helped me to refresh ViewPager's fragments. But instead of `getFragmentManager()` I used `getChildFragmentManager()` because got an exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions` (in `commitAllowingStateLoss()` line). I used ViewPager inside Fragment, that was so.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/21551357/2914140 helped me. You can find many solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add your fragment to your view and commit.

write something like this in your "onCreate".

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, YOUR_FRAGMENT);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

or replace the old one.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is the advertised behavior: **Your fragments are being restored**.

Actually, it should also be noted that it is merely chance that is causing Activity A to be recreated. It could be possible that Activity A still exists after B finishes which will not lead to execution of onCreate of A again.

---

*Why newInstance is not being called*?

> This happens because the fragments are actually in the FragmentManager of the killed activity. Therefore, they are restored when the activity is recreated. The tags of the fragments are usually:
>   **["android:switcher:" + your_pager_id + ":" + your_fragment_position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9293207/833622)**.