# WebViews inside ViewPager not always updating

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, android-viewpager

I have the next scenario

An activity with a FrameLayout. In the FrameLayout I load fragments using replace

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment contentToLoad = null;
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

...get the proper fragment depending of some logic 
contentToLoad = new FragmentDemoContent();

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fl_contentcontainer, contentToLoad);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

One of the fragments contains a ViewPager and a SlidingTabLayout (Copied from https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-SlidingTabLayout)

Inside the ViewPager I'm loading as pages other fragments, each fragment is a WebView that load a local content from assets. The adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter

When I first load this fragment everything works fine, and I can swipe and load all the pages. But If I load other fragment and I came back to load the fragment with the ViewPager again, I get random blank pages, sometimes is the first one, sometime others. Sometimes also when I swipe back the previous blank page appears, but not always

I have tried, with no luck:

1. Check if its a WebView problem. It is not, using instead of the
   fragments with the webviews blank default fragments with simply a
   textview, I get the random blank pages too.
2. Invalidate the views, the pager... after each scroll or page changed
3. This approach [ViewPager PagerAdapter not updating the View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view/7287121#7287121)
4. Set http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29
   to load all the pages

Any ideas or something  that we can try?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. At the child fragment we were using getSupportFragmentManager instead of getChildFragmentManager. After replacing it it works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Webview has rendering  issue it takes time to load you can use textView with

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("your html text"));
```

Comment: As I wrote I think is not a webview problem. Besides of that, I dont think load webcontent in a textview is a good idea.