# ViewPager2 and FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

I want to set the adapter of ViewPager2 to FragmentStatePagerAdapter but I get this error:

`Type mismatch. Required: (RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder!>?..RecyclerView.Adapter<*>?) Found: ViewPager2Adapter`

My ViewPagerAdapter class is

```
class ViewPager2Adapter(fm:FragmentManager) :FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    return when(position) {
        0 -> {
            MyScansListFragment()
        }
        1 -> {
            PurchasedItemsFragment()
        }
        else -> {
            Fragment()
        }
    }
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return 2
}

override fun getItemPosition(`object`: Any): Int {
    return POSITION_NONE
}}
```

And in the oncreateView() :

```
val viewPager2Adapter = ViewPager2Adapter(activity?.supportFragmentManager!!)
    binding!!.viewPager.adapter = viewPager2Adapter
```

Answer (score 2):

okay, let's change the code a little bit.
First of all, FragmentStatePagerAdapter has been deprecated.

FragmentStatePagerAdapter & FragmentPagerAdapter have been recently deprecated, and your code must look something like this. <strike>FragmentStatePagerAdapter</strike> and if you get your cursor over it and see details, there will be a statement "**Deprecated** *Switch to androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2 and use androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter instead.*"

try the following code.

```
class ViewPager2Adapter(private val listFragment: ArrayList<Fragment>,
                        fm: FragmentManager,
                        lifecycle: Lifecycle) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifecycle) {


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listFragment.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
       return listFragment[position]
    }
}
```

so, this is now kind of your universal viewpager adapter.
The next thing is we require fragments to be passed in here.

```
//I don't think you need Fragment() but since it's there in your list.

val fragmentList = listOf(MyScansListFragment(),  PurchasedItemsFragment(),Fragment())
val viewPager2Adapter = ViewPager2Adapter(fragmentList, activity?.supportFragmentManager!!, lifecycle)
binding!!.viewPager.adapter = viewPager2Adapter
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but since my fragments doesn't update when data is changed  I wanted to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter because of the answer in there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080045/fragmentpageradapter-notifydatasetchanged-not-working

Comment: so, that's an old question and FragmentStatePagerAdapter has been recently deprecated, even you must see your code look something like this. <strike>FragmentStatePagerAdapter</strike> and if you get your cursor over it and see details, there will be a statement " Deprecated
Switch to androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2 and use androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter instead."

Comment: even FragmentPagerAdapter has been deprecated for that as well android studio tells you to switch to FragmentStateAdapter.

Comment: @AbdulsametKılınçarslan if this answer helped you out don't forget to mark this answer as accepted and feel free to ask queries if you have any.