# Replace current Fragment in ViewPager on Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager`  and I have to replace the first `Fragment` if a certain action happens.

```
public static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    private TempChannel latestChannel;
    private VideosFragment.SortType sortType;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                if(latestChannel == null) {
                    return new LatestVideosFragment();
                }else{
                    return VideosFragment.getVideosFragment(latestChannel, sortType);
                }
            case 1:
                return new LiveVideosFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ConversationsFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Basically, when I click a channel in the `LatestVideosFragment`, the first position in the adapter should change to an instance of the `VideosFragment` class.

```
public void startLatestChannelFragment(TempChannel channel, VideosFragment.SortType sortType){
    adapter.setLatestChannel(channel, sortType);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d("x", "on channel started");
}
```

I assumed that calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter would update the fragment, but it does not. Also tried calling `invalidate(`) on the `ViewPager` without any effect. The `Fragment` is updated only if I go to the third tab, and then return to the first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the answers here for some good solutions: [ViewPager PagerAdapter not updating the View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view)

Basically overwriting `getItemPosition` in your  `PagerAdapter` will give you the desired effect.

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
     return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not imagine it would be so easy as to override a method