# Replacing Fragment in a Tablayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to replace a fragment in my `Tablayout` with a new `Fragment`, however everywhere i have looked uses:

```
                Fragment newFragment = new UserProfileFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                transaction.commit();
```

However, as i'm using `tablayout` and `viewpager`, i don't have anything like `R.id.fragment_container`. Below is my activity which the fragments are attached too.

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_home);


        userHomeToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.userHomeTabView);
        setSupportActionBar(userHomeToolbar);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new UserProfileFragment(), "Home");
        adapter.addFragment(new FootballGroundFragment(), "Grounds");
        adapter.addFragment(new UserSettingsFragment(), "Friends");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
        //you can leave it empty
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: then in your fragment in which you want change fragment create a container in that layout and inflate both fragments in that

Comment: How would i go about doing that?

Comment: you can see navigation drawer as a reference for container

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I have added an example as answer.Try it once, it may help

Comment: Hey xiimoss, Can you solve it? Please tell me how ..

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is replace a fragment in a viewpager, there have been many good solutions for it, check:

1) [Replace Fragment inside a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723964/replace-fragment-inside-a-viewpager)

or [Replace one Fragment with another in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588944/replace-one-fragment-with-another-in-viewpager)

or [Replace current Fragment in ViewPager on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342613/replace-current-fragment-in-viewpager-on-android)

2) Here is a good tutorial: 
http://www.pineappslab.com/post/fragments-viewpager/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a container in the fragment you want to have multiple fragments. For this you can either use **fragment tag** or **Frame Layout** in your **xml**.

Some what like this.

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/frame_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And in your fragment you can inflate them using fragment transaction. Note that in your fragment you have to use **childFragmentManager**.

**For example**

```
FragmentManager childFragMan = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction childFragTrans = childFragMan.beginTransaction();
ChildFragment fragB = new ChildFragment ();
childFragTrans.add(R.id.FRAGMENT_PLACEHOLDER, fragB);
childFragTrans.addToBackStack("B");
childFragTrans.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

By default FragmentPagerAdapter calls the getItem() method when there is no fragment associated with the given position. Therefore when you change the fragment at that position it is not updated. So one possible solution is to remove the old fragment present at that position from the fragment manager explicitly so that next time it adds the new fragment for that position.

It can be done like this:

Override the instantiateItem() method inside your ViewPagerAdapter class.

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment currentFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        Fragment actualFragment = getItem(position);

        if (actualFragment != currentFragment) {
            // Remove the old fragment
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.remove(currentFragment);
            transaction.commitNow();

            // The super class method takes care of adding the new fragment
            currentFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        }

        return currentFragment;
    }
```