# Images loading randomly into view pager with Glide and SimpleTarget

Tags: android, bitmap, android-viewpager, android-adapter, android-glide

I'm using `Glide` to load image into a `ViewPager` using an `PagerAdapter`.
When I load the images using the following method:

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(mImage).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(mImageView);
```

Everything works fine, but now I need to get the bitmap from glide and store it in a map when it loads for future edit, so I switched this method to the following one:

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(mImage).asBitmap().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {

                @Override
                public void onLoadStarted(Drawable placeholder) {
                    super.onLoadStarted(placeholder);
                    mImageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
                }

                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                    mBitmapMap.put(position, bitmap);
                    mInterface.onImageLoaded(position, bitmap);
                }
            });
```

But the result is that the image not always shown. I think it's some how related to the fact the glide loads images async and at some point it returns when `instatiateItem` method already finished running.

It looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view) is related. But the suggestions there did not help me. Has someone encountered this problem and has a solution for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution for this issue was to use another kind of target, instead of using the `SimpleTarget` object which I was using when I wrote the question I replaced it with the `BitmapImageViewTarget` object which I guess handles images asynchronously better. So the final code that I used for it is:

```
Glide.with(BaseApplication.getInstance()).load(newContent).asBitmap().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_action_picture).into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(mIvContent) {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadStarted(Drawable placeholder) {
                        super.onLoadStarted(placeholder);
                        mIvContent.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                        super.onResourceReady(resource, glideAnimation);
                        mBitmapMap.put(position, resource);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mIvContent.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        super.onLoadFailed(e, errorDrawable);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
```