# Recycler view adapter gets old data(adapter) even when view pager is displaying another fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-contextmenu

I have a ViewPager with 3 tabs, each tab loads a fragment, new instance of the same fragment class but with an extra parameter.

Below you can find the fragment class, I have a RecyclerView in that fragment, I am trying to open a context menu when the user long presses on an item in the RecyclerView.

I am able to display the context menu and get the position of the selected item for a single instance of a fragment, when I swipe to the next fragment I am getting the same index position, when I debugged further I find that I am getting the same adapter for the RecyclerView on the previous fragment. This can be seen when I log the adapter size for that RecyclerView.

Can anyone help me understand why I am getting the previous adapter data when I have swiped to a completely different instance of that fragment in the ViewPager, even when I can see the correct data in the Fragment and get the correct values in the `onBindViewHolder` method.

Below you can find the simplified code for the fragment class

```
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = HistoryFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private HistoryAdapter mHistoryAdapter;
    private List<Group> mGroups;

    private String mGroupType;

    /**
     * tried using a static int value to track which context menu was opened and on which fragment
     * refer post https://caughtinthemobileweb.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/android-viewpager-holds-reference-to-old-fragments/
     * BUG LOGGED AT https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19211
     * does not work :(
     */
    /*private static int selectedContextMenu;*/ // returns valid index as int is static, but adapter still has old data

    /**
     * The fragment argument for this fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_GROUP_TYPE = "group_type";

    public HistoryFragment() { }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment
     */
    public static HistoryFragment newInstance(String groupType) {
        HistoryFragment fragment = new HistoryFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_GROUP_TYPE, groupType);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewHistoryItem);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mGroups = new ArrayList<>();
        mHistoryAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(getActivity(), mGroups);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mHistoryAdapter);


        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        mGroupType = bundle.getString(ARG_GROUP_TYPE);
        if(mGroupType != null && !mGroupType.equals("")){
            loadDataFromDb();
        } else {
            if(IS_DEBUG_ON) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "invalid fragment arguments");
            getActivity().finish();
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        // int id = item.getItemId();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "position2: " + mHistoryAdapter.getSelectedItemPosition() + 
                " " + mGroups.get(mHistoryAdapter.getSelectedItemPosition()).getName()); // returns old data
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "size2: " + mHistoryAdapter.getItemCount()); // returns old data
        // Log.d(LOG_TAG, "position3: " + selectedContextMenu); // returns correct index, but cant use as adapter still has old data
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "position4: " + ((HistoryAdapter) mRecyclerView.getAdapter()).getSelectedItemPosition()); // returns old data
        return true;
    }

    private void loadDataFromDb(){
        new LoadGroups().execute();
    }

    class HistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoryFragment.HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private Context mContext;
        private List<Group> mList;
        private int mSelectedItemPosition;

        HistoryAdapter(Context mContext, List<Group> mList) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.mList = mList;
        }

        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
            View mView;
            TextView mTextViewName;
            TextView mTextViewDescription;
            ImageView mImageViewProfile;
            ImageView mImageCheck;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                this.mView = itemView;
                this.mTextViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewGroupName);
                this.mTextViewDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewGroupDescription);
                this.mImageViewProfile = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.groupImage);
                this.mImageCheck = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageCheck);
                this.mView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this); // registering listener
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                if(mGroupType.equals(GroupContract.GroupEntry.GROUP_TYPE_HISTORY_GROUP)){
                    menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.action_resubscribed_group, Menu.NONE, R.string.action_resubscribed_group);
                } else if(mGroupType.equals(GroupContract.GroupEntry.GROUP_TYPE_SUBSCRIBED_GROUP)){
                    if(!mList.get(getAdapterPosition()).isDefault()){
                        menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.action_unsubscribe_group, Menu.NONE, R.string.action_unsubscribe_group);
                    }
                    menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.action_mute, Menu.NONE, R.string.action_mute);
                    menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.action_view_group_info, Menu.NONE, R.string.action_view_group_info);

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_history, parent, false);
            return new HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            if(mGroupType.equals(GroupContract.GroupEntry.GROUP_TYPE_SUBSCRIBED_GROUP)){
                holder.mImageCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.mImageCheck.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            holder.mTextViewName.setText(mList.get(position).getName());
            holder.mTextViewDescription.setText(mList.get(position).getDescription());

            holder.mView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    // mSelectedItemPosition = position; // tried this, returns correct 
                    // selectedContextMenu = position; // also tried this, returns correct
                    mSelectedItemPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition(); // this also returns correct 
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "position1 - onBind: " + mSelectedItemPosition + " "+ mList.get(mSelectedItemPosition).getName()); // returns correct data
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holder) {
            holder.mView.setOnLongClickListener(null); // clearing listener to avoid collision between list items
            super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mList.size();
        }

        int getSelectedItemPosition() {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getter: " + mSelectedItemPosition); // this returns wrong data, shows that fragment is referring old adapter data
            return mSelectedItemPosition;
        }
    }

    // get data from db
    class LoadGroups extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            mGroups = GroupContract.getGroupEntriesFromDB(getActivity(), mGroupType);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            mHistoryAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(getActivity(), mGroups);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mHistoryAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Below you can find the ViewPager Adapter class

```
public class HomeTabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    HomeTabsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return HistoryFragment.newInstance("TYPE_1");
            case 1:
                return HistoryFragment.newInstance("TYPE_2");
            case 2:
                return HistoryFragment.newInstance("TYPE_3");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.text_type_1);
            case 1:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.text_type_2);
            case 2:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.text_type_3);
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Doesn't work even when I use this or not
    /*@Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        // try http://stackoverflow.com/a/8024557
        // return super.getItemPosition(object);
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, the use of RecyclerView.LayoutManager can be an issue, because you have a static class and the first two created fragments will have the same content (of the second one). The same is for the next fragments . Further, the getItemPosition(Object object) -> return POSITION_NONE is only usable with the FragmentStatePagerAdapter . The FragmentAdapter you have never changes the fragments, once created.
 So, I'd suggest instead of :

RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new  LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

to use

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

//or set an GridLayoutManager instead

use FragmentStatePagerAdapter if you plan to update the content of the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and fixed it by putting this on my fragment:

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
}
```

In your case you can call getRecycledViewPool when you change the tab.