# Viewpager Not Updating The View

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a bottomnavigation in the main activity that has 5 tabs in each file
There are 5 tabs in each of the Fragment
Everything works fine
But when it comes to other Fragment bottomnavigation, viewpager is not updated

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

}



private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    FrgPlayer.ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new FrgPlayer.ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new FrgJadval(), "a");
    adapter.addFragment(new FrgKholase(), "b");
    adapter.addFragment(new FrgAmar(), "c");
    adapter.addFragment(new FrgRokhdad(), "d");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

I do not know why the cause of the non-updating of ViewPager

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ViewPager PagerAdapter not updating the View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: @aaaaaa I'm sorry, what?