# Viewpager PageTranformer blocks UI changes onclick in some devices

Tags: android, android-viewpager, ontouch

I have used Custom ViewPager which extends `Viewpager` . I have used gesture detector to do the scroll event.

here is my code,

```
public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    public boolean isScrollEvent;
    public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(getContext(),new GestureListener());
        setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
        setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean res=gestureDetector.onTouchEvent((ev));
        Log.d("event", "interceotontouch      " + res);
        return res;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean res= gestureDetector.onTouchEvent((ev));
        if((ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL ||ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)) {
            if(isScrollEvent) {
                try {
                    endFakeDrag();
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
            return true;
        }
        Log.d("event", "ontouch      "+res);
        return res;
    }

    public void setScrollDuration(int duration) {
        mScroller.setScrollDuration(duration);
    }




    private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            isScrollEvent=false;
           Log.d("touch","singletap");
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
           Log.d("touch","fling");
            isScrollEvent=false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                if (diffY > 20) {
                    onSwipeDown();
                    return  false;
                } else if(diffY<-20){
                    onSwipeUp();
                    return  false;
                }
                else
                {
                    endFakeDrag();
                    int id = getCurrentItem();
                    setCurrentItem(id, true);
                }


            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;

        }
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                                float distanceX, float distanceY) {
         Log.d("touch", "scroll" + " " + distanceX);
            beginFakeDrag();
            fakeDragBy(-distanceY);
            isScrollEvent=true;
            return true;

        }
    }
    public void onSwipeUp() {
        setCurrentItem(getCurrentItem() + 1);

    }
    public void onSwipeDown() {
        setCurrentItem(getCurrentItem() - 1);

    }
}
```

And this is my `PageTranformer`,

```
public class VerticalPageTransformer implements android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        final float MIN_SCALE = 0.85f;
         final float MIN_ALPHA = 0.5f;

                if (position < -1) {
                    view.setAlpha(0);
                } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
                    view.setAlpha(1);
                    view.setTranslationX(-1 * view.getWidth() * position);
                    float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
                    view.setTranslationY(yPosition);
                    view.setScaleX(1);
                    view.setScaleY(1);
                } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
                    view.setAlpha(1 - position);
                    view.setTranslationX(-1 * view.getWidth() * position);
                    float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
                    view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
                    view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
                } else {
                    view.setAlpha(0);
                }
    }

}
```

Everything works fine. But the problem is , When I click something in the current page, **`onClick() event invoked`**. But it **`doesn't update`** the view. The view gets updated after changing the page.

This is my adapter,

```
public class MainViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<NHBean> newslist = new ArrayList<>();
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, hh:mm a");
    public MainViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("NewsUpdatePref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
        String serialized = preferences.getString("BOOKMARKS", null);
        if (serialized != null)
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(serialized, ",")));

    }

    public void addItems(List<NHBean> newslist) {
        this.newslist.clear();
        this.newslist.addAll(newslist);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final NHBean nhBean = newslist.get(position);
        Log.d("ImageURL"+position,nhBean.getImageUrl());
        ViewGroup layout;
        layout= (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, collection, false);


        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        TextView timeText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.time_text);
        TextView textHead = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text_head);
        ImageView shareNews = layout. findViewById(R.id.share_news);
        ImageView firstPage = layout. findViewById(R.id.first_page);
        final ImageView bookmark=layout.findViewById(R.id.bookmark);
        firstPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MainActivity)context).moveToFirstPage();
            }
        });
        shareNews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //code for share
                }
            }
        });
        bookmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("clicked","yes");
                if (list.contains(nhBean.getDate())) {
                    list.remove(nhBean.getDate());
                    bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark_not_added);
                } else {
                    bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark_added);
                    list.add(nhBean.getDate());
                }
                preferences.edit().putString("BOOKMARKS", TextUtils.join(",", list)).apply();

            }
        });

        try {
            timeText.setText(displayFormat.format(dateTimeFormat.parse(nhBean.getDate())));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

       text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MainActivity) context).setToolBarVisibility();

            }
        });

        if (list.contains(nhBean.getDate())) {
            bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark_added);
        } else {
            bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark_not_added);
        }
        textHead.setText(nhBean.getHeadline());
        text.setText(nhBean.getContent() + "\n");

        textHead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("text_head", nhBean.getHeadline());
                intent.putExtra("news_url", nhBean.getNewsUrl());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        collection.addView(layout);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View)view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return newslist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return null;
    }

    public NHBean getItem(int position) {
        return newslist.get(position);
    }


}
```

When I click these buttons, the onClick() is invoked. Look at bookmark button onclick, setImageResource() is not done. But surprisingly when I scroll, the button image is changed.

Edit:

My MainActivity code,

```
    mainViewPager = findViewById(R.id.flip_view);
    mainViewPagerAdapter = new MainViewPagerAdapter(this);
    mainViewPager.setAdapter(mainViewPagerAdapter);
    mainViewPager.setScrollDuration(300);
    mainViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new VerticalViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            if (position != 0 || !toolbar.getTitle().toString().equals(getString(R.string.allnews))) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
            } else
                swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
    updateNews();
```

And the method code,

```
public void updateNews() {
    try {
        final ArrayList<NHBean> headlines_1 = DBHelper.getInstance(this).getHeadlines();
        mainViewPagerAdapter.addItems(headlines_1);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And also the start animation for each page gets stuck when the page is selected.

Help me !!! Thanks in advance

Comment: can u please post the main activity where you have initialized the view pager?

Comment: @quicklearner please check edited question

Comment: add full code for main activity , i wanted to see ((MainActivity)context).moveToFirstPage(); method , atleast post appropriate code

Comment: @quicklearner it just setcurrentItem(0); And moving to first page is working fine. Just UI updates not happened

Comment: bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark_not_added); this?

Comment: @quicklearner yeah , It is not done. But when I scroll, the image is changed

Comment: scroll in recycler view /listview?

Comment: @quicklearner I am not using any nested scrollviews. I am just using a view with image and buttons. And when I am changing page by scrolling /swiping viewpager, the UI updates done. Let me know if you dont understand

Comment: for that you need to save state of fragment on scroll and restore back to same state , because the oncreate() gets called again every type you scroll to alternate position of fragment in viewpager

Comment: @quicklearner I didn't use fragment. I am just returning a view from instantiateItem()

Comment: would be really better if u just post enough code :)

Comment: @quicklearner I added adapter code and main activity code works fine. I am just displaying data . No complicated code in it.

Comment: alright ill check

Comment: @quicklearner The first page (before scrolling/swiping/fling) changes UI. When i scroll, any of pages can't update. I think the problem is with my gesture detection events

Comment: gesture methods get called or not when u swipe?

Comment: It gets called . Everything is working except updation

Comment: try using worker thread to update UI and let me know if it helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170836/discussion-between-quick-learner-and-jyoti-jk).

Comment: Did you tried calling  `notifyDataSetChanged()` ? check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view

Comment: @sunilsunny I am directly setting image when it is clicked.Why should I call notifyDataSetChanged().  And I tried that link solutions but none of those worked for me

Comment: The view is changing while scrolling right? So the issue in your case is somehow view not getting refreshed. So may be you can try calling  notifyDataSetChanged() and manually refresh the view.

Comment: @sunilsunny I accept your point but even the animation also not working. When the page is changed, the new page is displayed with animation(2 sec) . But it is also happening on scroll. Also I am not getting ripple effect on button click. I think the view is blocked from changing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the code,

I have used   **`android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`** in Manifest. After lots of research, I found this.

I just changed,

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after `onClick()` invoked.

Comment: Try destroyDrawingCache() after notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I found the issue.please check my question now.

Answer (score 0):

Override getItemPosition in your PagerAdapter like this:

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

This way, when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, the view pager will remove all views and reload them all. As so the reload effect is obtained.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() is costly.I have more that 100 or 200 pages . so it will cause performance issue. My problem is "View is blocked from updation/changes" . please check question clearly. And my code works api>23.

Comment: Try to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: I tried it. But it doesn't change anything. I think the problem is with gesturedetector or ontouchevent() in Vertical Viewpager

Comment: As it is related to api version may be `Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
            Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scroller.setAccessible(true);` this is creating problem!

Comment: I tried commenting those lines and tried without gesturedetector. Nothing helps

Comment: Then debug in your `ontouchevent()`. You may find the issue there.

Comment: I found the issue.please check my question now. If I didn't set pagetranformer, it works fine