# Replacing ViewPager Adapter changing only off-screen fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` that displays 10 fragments. However when I change the `FragmentPagerAdapter` and set it to the `ViewPager` only the not-currently-shown fragments are changed. I tried invalidating the `ViewPager`, calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the `FragmentPagerAdapter` and [this SO answer and only changing the data instead of the adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view)(and this answer is using a `PagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter` but without success.

This is how I initialize the `ViewPager`

```
viewPager = rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
changeData()
```

and then later for changing I call this function

```
fun changeData(params: List<CustomObject> = ArrayList()){
    viewPager.adapter = CustomCPagerAdapter(fragmentManager!!, params)
}
```

and the CustomPagerAdapter

```
class CustomPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager,
                         private var customDataSet: List<CustomObject>) 
    : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {  

    override fun getItem(pos: Int): Fragment {
        return CustomFragment.newInstance(customDataSet[pos])
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return customDataSet.size
    }
}
```

Why is the `ViewPager` keeping the displayed fragments even though a new `FragmentPagerAdapter` is added to it? How do I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter` because it doesn't keep the fragments in memory. The later adapter has some sort of optimization and doesn't force refresh already displayed fragments even when a new instance of `FragmentPagerAdapter` is set to the `ViewPager`.

From the docs about [`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter)

> This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the saved state of that fragment. This allows the pager to hold on to much less memory associated with each visited page as compared to FragmentPagerAdapter at the cost of potentially more overhead when switching between pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
fun changeData(params: List<CustomObject> = ArrayList()){
    viewPager.adapter = null 
    viewPager.adapter = CustomCPagerAdapter(fragmentManager!!, params)
}
```