# ViewPager2 and FragmentStateAdapter not updating on notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentstateadapter

I followed [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2) tutorial to create a Tab layout  with ViewPager2 and FragmentStateAdapter. In my adapter I have an ArrayList with data for the fragments which I then pass differently according to the position of the fragment. I am passing the data using the arguments, the same as described in the tutorial.

The data is passed correctly the first time, however then I am updating the data from the DemoCollectionAdapter (or Activity where the Adapter is initialized). After updating the data I am calling notifyDataSetChanged() but the data in the Fragments does not update.

I have also tried re-setting the TextViews' text in my Fragment by overriding the onResume method in my Fragment and this works fine for 5 out of my 7 fragments which is very weird. The array `enabledSchedule` is set by the arguments in the `OnViewCreated` method.

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d("DebugFrag-Frag", "I am the UI thread");
                swSlotOne.setChecked(enabledSchedule[0]);
                swSlotTwo.setChecked(enabledSchedule[1]);
                swSlotThree.setChecked(enabledSchedule[2]);
                swSlotFour.setChecked(enabledSchedule[3]);
            }
        });
    }
```

Am I updating the fragments' data in an inappropriate manner? The tutorial by Android does not seem to mention how to update the data then.

**Note** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view) question is different because it uses ViewPager not ViewPager2 and PagerAdapter not FragmentStateAdapter.

Comment: hey @uke you need to override override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return yourItemList[position].id.toLong()
    }

Comment: Thanks I'll try!

Comment: Hi @DeepakVajpayee, in 'yourItemList' you are storing an id for each entry? The array id is generally the same as the position, no?

Comment: It can be any unique property of object. In my case I have unique id for every object.

Comment: please note also override containsItem like below.
    override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean {
        return yourItemList.find { it.id.toLong() == itemId } != null
    }

Comment: Ok thanks, in my case I found that when I swipe to fragment 5, fragments 4 and 6 are created as well. Upon debugging I found that when fragment 6 is created, the data overrides that in the array. I temporarily fixed it by setting the following `viewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` . This means that the fragments are created only once, which I don't think is detrimental for my case since I have 7 fragments only. Maybe if I override getItemId and containsItem, the data overriding/replacement issue will be fixed.

Comment: Sorry didn't get your point  "I found that when fragment 6 is created, the data overrides that in the array"?  please elaborate this linke. @Luke

Comment: For whatever reason (could be a bug from my end), I have 7 fragments in total and a List of 7 objects corresponding to each fragment. At a point in my code I update all the fragments (and I confirmed and made sure that the List was being updated correctly). Then when I press on or swipe to fragment 5, I noticed that fragments 4 and 6 were being created as well (it's the way viewpager works (the offscreen pages). When fragments 4 and 5 are created, the data in my List is correct. When fragment 6 is created, I noticed that the data in my List for the last three fragments changes.